# Use dynamic name for new column/variable in `dplyr`

Tags: r, dplyr, r-faq

I want to use `dplyr::mutate()` to create multiple new columns in a data frame. The column names and their contents should be dynamically generated.

Example data from iris:

```
library(dplyr)
iris <- as_tibble(iris)
```

I've created a function to mutate my new columns from the `Petal.Width` variable:

```
multipetal <- function(df, n) {
    varname <- paste("petal", n , sep=".")
    df <- mutate(df, varname = Petal.Width * n)  ## problem arises here
    df
}
```

Now I create a loop to build my columns:

```
for(i in 2:5) {
    iris <- multipetal(df=iris, n=i)
}
```

However, since mutate thinks varname is a literal variable name, the loop only creates one new variable (called varname) instead of four (called petal.2 - petal.5).

How can I get `mutate()` to use my dynamic name as variable name?

Comment: The vignette doesn't even mention `mutate_`, and it really isn't obvious from the other functions how to use it.

Comment: I have struggled to understand the `quosure` et al. documentation for years. While the vignette link above no longer works, that comment lead me to this summary to tidyevaluation: https://shipt.tech/https-shipt-tech-advanced-programming-and-non-standard-evaluation-with-dplyr-e043f89deb3d. I finally understand! Thank you.

Comment: `dplyr` provides [this excellent vignette on Programming with dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html) that covers this.

Comment: Compared to base R it seems overly complex in dplyr get have dynamic names when looping ...

Comment: If you need the same operation several times it usually tells you that your data format is not optimal. You want a longer format with `n` being a column in the data.frame (see my answer below)

Comment: @MarioReutter optimal _for what_? I disagree that e.g. replacing 10 columns of 1 million rows with a key-value column of 10 million rows is unambiguously an improvement. Looping over column names has always been and should remain a perfectly acceptable thing to do, "tidiness" be damned.

Comment: @Markm0705 think of Dplyr/Rlang as implementing a succinct macro/metaprogramming DSL on top of the base R functionality of `as.symbol`, `substitute`, etc. which can be clunky and verbose. I like what they've done, but I really dislike all the new terminology, the constant churn in design, and the overly-complicated descriptions in the documentation, as if this were an arcane and obscure thing that people shouldn't need to do.

Comment: @shadowtalker If you need the slightly better performance for large data sets or a function that will be used myriads of times, I also encourage you to use the more efficient, wider data frame and a for loop. In many cases, however, the better readability of your code will save more working time than the lower run time of your script.
Edit: Reading your other comments, I realize you are a far more advanced programmer than I am. It seems like you know what you are doing and you can pick the solution that suits your problem best. For beginners, however, I argue that tidyness can help learning.

Answer (score 372, accepted):

Since you are dynamically building a variable name as a character value, it makes more sense to do assignment using standard data.frame indexing which allows for character values for column names. For example:

```
multipetal <- function(df, n) {
    varname <- paste("petal", n , sep=".")
    df[[varname]] <- with(df, Petal.Width * n)
    df
}
```

The `mutate` function makes it very easy to name new columns via named parameters. But that assumes you know the name when you type the command. If you want to dynamically specify the column name, then you need to also build the named argument.

---

### dplyr version >= 1.0

With the latest dplyr version you can use the syntax from the `glue` package when naming parameters when using `:=`. So here the `{}` in the name grab the value by evaluating the expression inside.

```
multipetal <- function(df, n) {
  mutate(df, "petal.{n}" := Petal.Width * n)
}
```

If you are passing a column name to your function, you can use `{{}}` in the string as well as for the column name

```
meanofcol <- function(df, col) {
  mutate(df, "Mean of {{col}}" := mean({{col}}))
}
meanofcol(iris, Petal.Width)
```

---

### dplyr version >= 0.7

`dplyr` starting with version 0.7 allows you to use `:=` to dynamically assign parameter names. You can write your function as:

```
# --- dplyr version 0.7+---
multipetal <- function(df, n) {
    varname <- paste("petal", n , sep=".")
    mutate(df, !!varname := Petal.Width * n)
}
```

For more information, see the documentation available form `vignette("programming", "dplyr")`.

---

### dplyr (>=0.3 & <0.7)

Slightly earlier version of `dplyr` (>=0.3 <0.7), encouraged the use of "standard evaluation" alternatives to many of the functions. See the Non-standard evaluation vignette for more information (`vignette("nse")`).

So here, the answer is to use `mutate_()` rather than `mutate()` and do:

```
# --- dplyr version 0.3-0.5---
multipetal <- function(df, n) {
    varname <- paste("petal", n , sep=".")
    varval <- lazyeval::interp(~Petal.Width * n, n=n)
    mutate_(df, .dots= setNames(list(varval), varname))
}
```

---

### dplyr < 0.3

Note this is also possible in older versions of `dplyr` that existed when the question was originally posed. It requires careful use of `quote` and `setName`:

```
# --- dplyr versions < 0.3 ---
multipetal <- function(df, n) {
    varname <- paste("petal", n , sep=".")
    pp <- c(quote(df), setNames(list(quote(Petal.Width * n)), varname))
    do.call("mutate", pp)
}
```

Comment: `do.call()` probably doesn't do what you think it does: http://rpubs.com/hadley/do-call2. See also the nse vignette in the dev version of dplyr.

Comment: So if I understand your point @hadley, I've updated the `do.call` above to use `do.call("mutate")` and to quote `df` in the list. Is that what you were suggesting? And when the `lazyeval` version of `dplyr` is the released version, then `mutate_(df, .dots= setNames(list(~Petal.Width * n), varname))` would be a better solution?

Comment: @MrFlick yes and yes :)

Comment: What if I need the variable column header not only on the left hand side of the assignment but also on the right? e.g. `mutate(df, !!newVar := (!!var1 + !!var2) / 2)` does not work :(

Comment: @Mario Reutter: Did you ever got an answer to your comment? I asked the same question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69003844/using-a-composite-to-call-a-variable-dynmically-in-custom-build-function-with-dp) and would love to get it solved!

Comment: @MsGISRocker Look at the `meanofcol()` example in the answer. It uses column names on both sides.

Comment: @MrFlick: Yes, but I would like to combine a column name with a string to call a column, such as ````mutate(df, "Mean of {{col}}" := mean("{{col}} for mean"))````, The column name is a composite of another column's name ````{{col}}```` and a suffix or prefix ````" for mean"````. Ideally, some quick and easy code.

Comment: @MsGISRocker If you need to use string for column names, use the `.data` pronoun. Maybe `mean(.data[[glue::glue("{{col}} for mean")]])`

Comment: This [link](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#indirection-2) can be helpful. You should use `.data[[col]]` if `col` contains the name of the column as a character string. You should use `{{col}}` if `col` holds a promise as in the post above, and as explained in the link.

Comment: @MarioReutter @msgisrocker Try:  `mutate(df, !!newVar := (df[ ,var1] + df[,var2]) / 2)`

Comment: Thank you, @OliverHumphreys! But if I have to rereference the df with base R within `mutate`, I can just use base R entirely : `df[,newVar] = (df[,var1] + df[,var2]) / 2` (unless it shall be used in a pipe).

Comment: `mutate(outvar = {{varname1}} - {{varname2}})` results in "Error in local_error_context(dots = dots, .index = i, mask = mask) :  promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?" whereas `mutate(outvar = get(varname1) - get(varname2))` "just works" for me. (dplyr v1.0.9)

Comment: @BrianD if get() works then your values are likely strings and not symbols as {{}} would expect. If you have an issue with promises already under evaluation then you have an issuer with variable names possibly being reused and matching column names where you don’t expect. Hard to say without seeing any code. But if you have an issue, you should create your own question.

Comment: For anyone reading this coming from other questions marked as duplicate, these techniques with `{{` and `!!` are the official and correct tools for injecting a variable name into *any* Dplyr function, not only assignment with `:=`. It might be helpful to add a note of this to the answer, so that this answer can be come "canonical" with respect to marking other questions as duplicates.

Comment: also, MrFlick, may I suggest to also add a note (this comment section is already far too long) that the only version that seems to work with non-anonymous functions in loops is the one with a single curly operator. code was too long for comment, see https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/6784

Comment: Note in the solution for "dplyr version >= 1.0", `col` is NOT a string, that is, it equals `Petal.Width`, not `"Petal.Width"`. If you put the latter it won't work, as the `"` will become part of the code.

Answer (score 83):

In the new release of `dplyr` (`0.6.0` awaiting in April 2017), we can also do an assignment (`:=`) and pass variables as column names by unquoting (`!!`) to not evaluate it

```
 library(dplyr)
 multipetalN <- function(df, n){
      varname <- paste0("petal.", n)
      df %>%
         mutate(!!varname := Petal.Width * n)
 }

 data(iris)
 iris1 <- tbl_df(iris)
 iris2 <- tbl_df(iris)
 for(i in 2:5) {
     iris2 <- multipetalN(df=iris2, n=i)
 }
```

Checking the output based on @MrFlick's `multipetal` applied on 'iris1'

```
identical(iris1, iris2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: why do you need to use `:=` for assignments when unquoting a variable  (i.e. `!!varname`)?

Comment: this is a good solution, but it only works when we're passing character vectors, not numerics directly (it works here because of your paste step before).

Answer (score 51):

After a lot of trial and error, I found the pattern `!!rlang::sym("my variable"))` (in earlier R versions: `UQ(rlang::sym("my variable")))`) really useful for working with strings and dplyr verbs. It seems to work in a lot of surprising situations.

Here's an example with `mutate`. We want to create a function that adds together two columns, where you pass the function both column names as strings. We can use this pattern, together with the assignment operator `:=`, to do this.

```
## Take column `name1`, add it to column `name2`, and call the result `new_name`
mutate_values <- function(new_name, name1, name2){
  mtcars %>% 
    mutate(!!rlang::sym(new_name) :=  !!rlang::sym(name1) + !!rlang::sym(name2))
}
mutate_values('test', 'mpg', 'cyl')
```

The pattern works with other `dplyr` functions as well. Here's `filter`:

```
## filter a column by a value 
filter_values <- function(name, value){
  mtcars %>% 
    filter(!!rlang::sym(name) != value)
}
filter_values('gear', 4)
```

Or `arrange`:

```
## transform a variable and then sort by it 
arrange_values <- function(name, transform){
  mtcars %>% 
    arrange((!!rlang::sym(name)) %>% (!!rlang::sym(transform)))
}
arrange_values('mpg', 'sin')
```

For `select`, you don't need to use the pattern. Instead you can use `!!`:

```
## select a column 
select_name <- function(name){
  mtcars %>% 
    select(!!name)
}
select_name('mpg')
```

Comment: Your tips works very well, but I have a little issue. I change  an initial column `myCol` to an url (for example), and copy the old column `myColInitialValue` at the end of the dataframe `df` with a new name. But a `which(colnames(df)=='myCol')` send back the col # of `myColInitialValue`. I didn't write an issue yet because I didn't found a reprex. My goal is for the `escape` parameter of `DT::datatable()`. I use `escape=FALSE` in waiting that. With constants it doesn't work also but the [DT package](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/blob/master/R/datatables.R) seems also get the bad # column. :)

Comment: My question [dplyr - mutate: use dynamic variable names, works well, but seems not work with # column for `escape` an `DT::datatable`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57123813/10489562)

Comment: It seems than dynamic variables are not the cause. (btw reprex added)

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Here is a super-simple example of how I used it: `varname = sym("Petal.Width"); ggplot(iris, aes(x=!!varname)) + geom_histogram()`

Comment: This worked for me inside a formula where !!varname wasn't working.

Comment: `sym()` is included by default in dplyr. see `help(sym)`.

Comment: which library does `UQ` come from?

Comment: `UQ` comes from `rlang` but is deprecated

Comment: You should now use `!!rlang::sym(name)` instead of `UQ(rlang::sym(name))`

Comment: Is there something simpler that `UQ(rlang::sym("string"))` for `mutate`?

Answer (score 26):

With [`rlang 0.4.0`](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/) we have curly-curly operators (`{{}}`) which makes this very easy. When a dynamic column name shows up on the left-hand side of an assignment, use `:=`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

iris1 <- tbl_df(iris)

multipetal <- function(df, n) {
   varname <- paste("petal", n , sep=".")
   mutate(df, {{varname}} := Petal.Width * n)
}

multipetal(iris1, 4)

# A tibble: 150 x 6
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species petal.4
#          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>     <dbl>
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa      0.8
# 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa      0.8
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa      0.8
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa      0.8
# 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa      0.8
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa      1.6
# 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa      1.2
# 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa      0.8
# 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa      0.8
#10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa      0.4
# … with 140 more rows
```

We can also pass quoted/unquoted variable names to be assigned as column names.

```
multipetal <- function(df, name, n) {
   mutate(df, {{name}} := Petal.Width * n)
}

multipetal(iris1, temp, 3)

# A tibble: 150 x 6
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species  temp
#          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>   <dbl>
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa  0.6  
# 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa  0.6  
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa  0.6  
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa  0.6  
# 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa  0.6  
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa  1.2  
# 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa  0.900
# 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa  0.6  
# 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa  0.6  
#10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa  0.3  
# … with 140 more rows
```

It works the same with

```
multipetal(iris1, "temp", 3)
```

Comment: or `mutate(df, 'petal.{n}' := Petal.Width * n)`

Comment: NB this approach fails when passing character vectors to the function within a loop - then a column will be created with the name of the function argument

Answer (score 14):

Here's another version, and it's arguably a bit simpler.

```
multipetal <- function(df, n) {
    varname <- paste("petal", n, sep=".")
    df<-mutate_(df, .dots=setNames(paste0("Petal.Width*",n), varname))
    df
}

for(i in 2:5) {
    iris <- multipetal(df=iris, n=i)
}

> head(iris)
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species petal.2 petal.3 petal.4 petal.5
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa     0.4     0.6     0.8       1
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa     0.4     0.6     0.8       1
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa     0.4     0.6     0.8       1
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa     0.4     0.6     0.8       1
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa     0.4     0.6     0.8       1
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa     0.8     1.2     1.6       2
```

Answer (score 5):

You may enjoy package [`friendlyeval`](https://github.com/MilesMcBain/friendlyeval) which presents a simplified tidy eval API and documentation for newer/casual `dplyr` users.

You are creating strings that you wish `mutate` to treat as column names. So using `friendlyeval` you could write:

```
multipetal <- function(df, n) {
  varname <- paste("petal", n , sep=".")
  df <- mutate(df, !!treat_string_as_col(varname) := Petal.Width * n)
  df
}

for(i in 2:5) {
  iris <- multipetal(df=iris, n=i)
}
```

Which under the hood calls `rlang` functions that check `varname` is legal as column name.

`friendlyeval` code can be converted to equivalent plain tidy eval code at any time with an RStudio addin.

Comment: I don't think this package is available anymore

Comment: it is and it works better than anything above ! When everything failed with case_when() this worked flawlessly

Answer (score 4):

I am also adding an answer that augments this a little bit because I came to this entry when searching for an answer, and this had almost what I needed, but I needed a bit more, which I got via @MrFlik 's answer and the R lazyeval vignettes.

I wanted to make a function that could take a dataframe and a vector of column names (as strings) that I want to be converted from a string to a Date object.  I couldn't figure out how to make `as.Date()` take an argument that is a string and convert it to a column, so I did it as shown below.

Below is how I did this via SE mutate (`mutate_()`) and the `.dots` argument.  Criticisms that make this better are welcome.

```
library(dplyr)

dat <- data.frame(a="leave alone",
                  dt="2015-08-03 00:00:00",
                  dt2="2015-01-20 00:00:00")

# This function takes a dataframe and list of column names
# that have strings that need to be
# converted to dates in the data frame
convertSelectDates <- function(df, dtnames=character(0)) {
    for (col in dtnames) {
        varval <- sprintf("as.Date(%s)", col)
        df <- df %>% mutate_(.dots= setNames(list(varval), col))
    }
    return(df)
}

dat <- convertSelectDates(dat, c("dt", "dt2"))
dat %>% str
```

Answer (score 4):

While I enjoy using dplyr for interactive use, I find it extraordinarily tricky to do this using dplyr because you have to go through hoops to use lazyeval::interp(), setNames, etc. workarounds.

Here is a simpler version using base R, in which it seems more intuitive, to me at least, to put the loop inside the function, and which extends @MrFlicks's solution.

```
multipetal <- function(df, n) {
   for (i in 1:n){
      varname <- paste("petal", i , sep=".")
      df[[varname]] <- with(df, Petal.Width * i)
   }
   df
}
multipetal(iris, 3)
```

Comment: +1, although I still use `dplyr` a lot in non-interactive settings, using it with variabel input inside a function uses very clunky syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative: use `{}` inside quotation marks to easily create dynamic names. This is similar to other solutions but not exactly the same, and I find it easier.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

iris <- as_tibble(iris)

multipetal <- function(df, n) {
  df <- mutate(df, "petal.{n}" := Petal.Width * n)  ## problem arises here
  df
}

for(i in 2:5) {
  iris <- multipetal(df=iris, n=i)
}
iris
```

I think this comes from `dplyr 1.0.0` but not sure (I also have `rlang 4.7.0` if it matters).

Answer (score 0):

If you need the same operation several times it usually tells you that your data format is not optimal. You want a longer format with `n` being a column in the data.frame that can be achieved by a cross join:

```
library(tidyverse)
iris %>% mutate(identifier = 1:n()) %>% #necessary to disambiguate row 102 from row 143 (complete duplicates)
   full_join(tibble(n = 1:5), by=character()) %>% #cross join for long format
   mutate(petal = Petal.Width * n) %>% #calculation in long format
   pivot_wider(names_from=n, values_from=petal, names_prefix="petal.width.") #back to wider format (if desired)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 150 x 11
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species identifier petal.width.1 petal.width.2 petal.width.3
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>        <int>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa           1           0.2           0.4           0.6
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa           2           0.2           0.4           0.6
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa           3           0.2           0.4           0.6
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa           4           0.2           0.4           0.6
 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa           5           0.2           0.4           0.6
 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa           6           0.4           0.8           1.2
 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa           7           0.3           0.6           0.9
 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa           8           0.2           0.4           0.6
 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa           9           0.2           0.4           0.6
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa          10           0.1           0.2           0.3
# ... with 140 more rows, and 2 more variables: petal.width.4 <dbl>, petal.width.5 <dbl>
```