# How to pass dynamic column names in dplyr into custom function?

Tags: r, dynamic, dataset, dplyr, names

I have a dataset with the following structure:

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’ and 'data.frame':  10 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ GdeName  : chr  "Aeugst am Albis" "Aeugst am Albis" "Aeugst am Albis" "Aeugst am Albis" ...
 $ Partei   : chr  "BDP" "CSP" "CVP" "EDU" ...
 $ Stand1971: num  NA NA 4.91 NA 3.21 ...
 $ Stand1975: num  NA NA 5.389 0.438 4.536 ...
 $ Stand1979: num  NA NA 6.2774 0.0195 3.4355 ...
 $ Stand1983: num  NA NA 4.66 1.41 3.76 ...
 $ Stand1987: num  NA NA 3.48 1.65 5.75 ...
```

I want to provide a function which allows to compute the difference between any value, and I would like to do this using `dplyr`s `mutate` function like so: (assume the parameters `from` and `to` are passed as arguments)

```
from <- "Stand1971"
to <- "Stand1987"

data %>%
  mutate(diff = from - to)
```

Of course, this doesn't work, as `dplyr` uses non-standard evaluation. And I know there's now an elegant solution to the problem using `mutate_`, and I've read [this vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html), but I still can't get my head around it.

What to do?

Here's the first few rows of the dataset for a reproducible example

```
structure(list(GdeName = c("Aeugst am Albis", "Aeugst am Albis", 
"Aeugst am Albis", "Aeugst am Albis", "Aeugst am Albis", "Aeugst am Albis", 
"Aeugst am Albis", "Aeugst am Albis", "Aeugst am Albis", "Aeugst am Albis"
), Partei = c("BDP", "CSP", "CVP", "EDU", "EVP", "FDP", "FGA", 
"FPS", "GLP", "GPS"), Stand1971 = c(NA, NA, 4.907306434, NA, 
3.2109535926, 18.272143463, NA, NA, NA, NA), Stand1975 = c(NA, 
NA, 5.389079711, 0.4382328556, 4.5363022622, 18.749259742, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), Stand1979 = c(NA, NA, 6.2773722628, 0.0194647202, 
3.4355231144, 25.294403893, NA, NA, NA, 2.7055961071), Stand1983 = c(NA, 
NA, 4.6609804428, 1.412940467, 3.7563539244, 26.277246489, 0.8529335746, 
NA, NA, 2.601878177), Stand1987 = c(NA, NA, 3.4767860929, 1.6535933856, 
5.7451770193, 22.146844746, NA, 3.7453183521, NA, 13.702211858
)), .Names = c("GdeName", "Partei", "Stand1971", "Stand1975", 
"Stand1979", "Stand1983", "Stand1987"), class = c("tbl_df", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but guessing from the context, you might be better over with a tidy data set that you could just use `lead(x) - x` to compute the differences between subsequent values for all years at once.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Using the latest version of dplyr (>=0.7), you can use the `rlang` `!!` (bang-bang) operator.

```
library(tidyverse)
from <- "Stand1971"
to <- "Stand1987"

data %>%
  mutate(diff=(!!as.name(from))-(!!as.name(to)))
```

You just need to convert the strings to names with `as.name` and then insert them into the expression. Unfortunately I seem to have to use a few more parenthesis than I would like, but the `!!` operator seems to fall in a weird order-of-operations order.

*Original answer, dplyr (0.3-<0.7):*

From that vignette (`vignette("nse","dplyr")`), use lazyeval's `interp()` function

```
library(lazyeval)

from <- "Stand1971"
to <- "Stand1987"

data %>%
  mutate_(diff=interp(~from - to, from=as.name(from), to=as.name(to)))
```

Comment: Why is this approach more "sexy" (or preferred) than using `paste`?

Comment: interp() helps to capture the appropriate environments as well which is more important when you have more complicated scoping or non-base functions

Comment: @wnstnsmth as well as capturing environments, the interp appraoch will always work regardless of the name of the variables. Using paste is just putting a ticking time bug bomb into your code.

Comment: What if I want my new column name (diff in this example) to be dynamic as well? The same construction doesn't seem to work on the LHS of the mutate assignment.

Comment: @DanTan Use `mutate(!!diff :=(!!as.name(from))-(!!as.name(to)))`. The `:=` allows you to change the name of the new column on the left of the equals. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/26003574/2372064

Answer (score 20):

You can use `.data` inside `dplyr` chain now.

```
library(dplyr)
from <- "Stand1971"
to <- "Stand1987"

data %>% mutate(diff = .data[[from]] - .data[[to]])
```

Another option is to use `sym` with bang-bang (`!!`)

```
data %>% mutate(diff = !!sym(from) - !!sym(to))
```

---

In base R, we can use :

```
data$diff <- data[[from]] - data[[to]]
```

Comment: This answer is perfect, however in other parts of the code I use the glue syntax ```{var}``` to do this. It however doesn't work within this context.

Is there a .data equivalent in the glue syntax that dplyr can use now?

Comment: Have you tried with `{.data[var]}` ? You can maybe ask a new question regarding your specific case.