# Function writing passing column reference to group_by

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I'm very new to R. Trying to define a function that groups a data set (group_by) and then creates summary statistics based on the groupings (dplyr, summarise_each).

Without defining a function the following works:

```
sum_stat <- data %>%
  group_by(column) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(mean), var1:var20)
```

The following function form does not work:

```
sum_stat <- function(data, column){
  data %>%
    group_by(column) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(mean), var1:var20)
}

sum_stat(data, column)
```

The error message returned is:

Error: unknown column 'column'

Comment: What does `data` look like?

Comment: dplyr has some hoops when you pass the name of a column in a variable. This seems to be the answer, but is rather ugly: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29678435/1191259

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the usual way you'd do this:

```
foo <- function(data,column){
  data %>%
    group_by_(.dots = column) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(mean))
}

foo(mtcars,"cyl")
foo(mtcars,"gear")
```