# Paste in column names into dplyr::mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

Using dplyr it's easy to create a new column as a function of other columns

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(iris, Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width)
```

Unfortunately, I have a situation where I need to paste these column names into mutate. I've tried unquoting the strings but that does not work:

```
mutate(iris, print("Sepal.Length",quote=FALSE) + print("Sepal.Width",quote=FALSE))
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### Update

This doesn't work anymore. See Ronak's answer below:

[How to pass dynamic column names in dplyr into custom function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66913972/680068)

##### Outdated answer

Try below:

```
mutate_(iris, "Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width")
```

Notice _ underscore after mutate_