# Automatically generate new variable names using dplyr mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to create variable names dynamically while using dplyr; although, I’d be fine with a non-dplyr solution as well.

For Example:

```
data(iris)
library(dplyr) 

iris <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(
    lag_Sepal.Length = lag(Sepal.Length),
    lag_Sepal.Width  = lag(Sepal.Width),
    lag_Petal.Length = lag(Petal.Length)
  ) %>%
  ungroup

head(iris)

    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species lag_Sepal.Length lag_Sepal.Width
             (dbl)       (dbl)        (dbl)       (dbl)  (fctr)            (dbl)           (dbl)
    1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa               NA              NA
    2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa              5.1             3.5
    3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa              4.9             3.0
    4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa              4.7             3.2
    5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa              4.6             3.1
    6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa              5.0             3.6
    Variables not shown: lag_Petal.Length (dbl)
```

But, instead of doing this three times, I want to create 100 of these “lag” variables that take in the name:  lag_original variable name. I’m trying to figure out how to do this without typing the new variable name 100 times, but I’m coming up short.

I’ve looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003574/r-dplyr-mutate-use-dynamic-variable-names) example and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35349130/paste-in-column-names-into-dplyrmutate) example elsewhere on SO. They are similar, but I’m not quite able to piece together the specific solution I need. Any help is appreciated!

**Edit**
Thanks to @BenFasoli for the inspiration. I took his answer and tweaked it just a bit to get the solution I needed. 
I also used [This RStudio Blog](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/06/27/dplyr-0-5-0/) and [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27027347/mutate-each-summarise-each-in-dplyr-how-do-i-select-certain-columns-and-give). The "lag" in the variable name is trailing instead of leading, but I can live with that.

My final code is posted here in case it’s helpful to anyone else:

```
lagged <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate_at(
    vars(Sepal.Length:Petal.Length),
    funs("lag" = lag)) %>%
  ungroup

# A tibble: 6 x 8
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Sepal.Length_lag Sepal.Width_lag
         <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>  <fctr>            <dbl>           <dbl>
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa               NA              NA
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa              5.1             3.5
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa              4.9             3.0
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa              4.7             3.2
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa              4.6             3.1
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa              5.0             3.6
# ... with 1 more variables: Petal.Length_lag <dbl>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mutate_all` (or `mutate_at` for specific columns) then prepend `lag_` to the column names.

```
data(iris)
library(dplyr) 

lag_iris <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate_all(funs(lag(.))) %>%
  ungroup
colnames(lag_iris) <- paste0('lag_', colnames(lag_iris))

head(lag_iris)

  lag_Sepal.Length lag_Sepal.Width lag_Petal.Length lag_Petal.Width lag_Species
             <dbl>           <dbl>            <dbl>           <dbl>      <fctr>
1               NA              NA               NA              NA      setosa
2              5.1             3.5              1.4             0.2      setosa
3              4.9             3.0              1.4             0.2      setosa
4              4.7             3.2              1.3             0.2      setosa
5              4.6             3.1              1.5             0.2      setosa
6              5.0             3.6              1.4             0.2      setosa
```

Comment: Thanks for the inspiration. I took your answer and tweaked it just a bit to get the solution I needed. I also used [This RStudio Blog]( https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/06/27/dplyr-0-5-0/) and [This SO post]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27027347/mutate-each-summarise-each-in-dplyr-how-do-i-select-certain-columns-and-give).

My final code is posted here in case it’s helpful to anyone else:

`lagged <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate_at(
    vars(Sepal.Length:Petal.Length),
    funs("lag" = lag)) %>%
  ungroup`

Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a data.table approach. I chose columns with numbers in this case. What you want to do is to choose column names and create new column names in advance. Then, you apply `shift()`, which works like `lag()` and `lead()` in the dplyr package, to each of the columns you chose.

```
library(data.table)

# Crate a df for this demo.
mydf <- iris

# Choose columns that you want to apply lag() and create new colnames.
cols = names(iris)[sapply(iris, is.numeric)]
anscols = paste("lag_", cols, sep = "")

# Apply shift() to each of the chosen columns.
setDT(mydf)[, (anscols) := shift(.SD, 1, type = "lag"),
            .SDcols = cols]

     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species lag_Sepal.Length lag_Sepal.Width
 1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa               NA              NA
 2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa              5.1             3.5
 3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa              4.9             3.0
 4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa              4.7             3.2
 5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa              4.6             3.1
 ---                                                                                             
146:          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica              6.7             3.3
147:          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica              6.7             3.0
148:          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica              6.3             2.5
149:          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica              6.5             3.0
150:          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica              6.2             3.4
     lag_Petal.Length lag_Petal.Width
  1:               NA              NA
  2:              1.4             0.2
  3:              1.4             0.2
  4:              1.3             0.2
  5:              1.5             0.2
 ---                                 
146:              5.7             2.5
147:              5.2             2.3
148:              5.0             1.9
149:              5.2             2.0
150:              5.4             2.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're also happy with a non-dplyr, try this:

```
lagger <- function(x, n) c(rep(NA,n), head(x,-n) )
iris[paste0("lag_", names(iris) )] <- lapply(iris, lagger, n=1)

head(iris,2)[-(1:5)]
#  lag_Sepal.Length lag_Sepal.Width lag_Petal.Length lag_Petal.Width lag_Species
#1               NA              NA               NA              NA          NA
#2              5.1             3.5              1.4             0.2           1
```