# Mutate multiple columns with a certain condition in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

I have this data

```
M1  M2  M3 UCL
1   2   3   1.5
```

I would like to make new columns with this condition:

If M1 is more than UCL, MM1 will be "UP" and otherwise "NULL"

If M2 is more than UCL, MM2 will be "UP" and otherwise "NULL"

If M3 is more than UCL, MM3 will be "UP" and otherwise "NULL"

```
M1  M2  M3 UCL   | MM1  MM2 MM3
1   2   3   1.5  | NULL UP  UP
```

But I have several M column (like M1~M1005) so that I would like to make some code such as mutate_each and mutate_at. How do I use the function using mutate and ifelse in order to make new columns under a particular condition?

Comment: Maybe you could look at this post https://www.enchufa2.es/archives/programming-with-dplyr-by-using-dplyr.html to see how to use string to select column (but I don't know if it will work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple `dplyr` solution. Note that it is easier to add a suffix to the new variables e.g. to get `M1_M` rather than `MM1`. However, you can set the `colnames` afterwards if you were keen to rename them (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340180/automatically-generate-new-variable-names-using-dplyr-mutate) on how to do that).

I show the result as a `tibble` so you can see the column types. Note that once a new column has a both an `UP` and an `NA` in it, it will change from a logical type to a character type.

```
library(dplyr)

textdata <- "M1  M2  M3 UCL
1   2   3   1.5"

mydf <- read.table(text = textdata, header = T)

mydf %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(starts_with("M")), funs(M = ifelse(. > UCL, "UP", NA))) %>% 
    tibble::as.tibble()

# A tibble: 1 x 7
     M1    M2    M3   UCL  M1_M  M2_M  M3_M
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> <chr> <chr>
1     1     2     3   1.5    NA    UP    UP
```

Comment: it looks like `mutate_if(is.integer, as.numeric) %>%` is not needed. Confirm, please?

Comment: Thanks @RickPack, have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

With base R:

```
dt <- read.table(text="M1  M2  M3 UCL
1   2   3   1.5",header=T)

ncols <- ncol(dt)
dt <- cbind(dt, ifelse(subset(df, select=M1:M3) > dt[,"UCL"], "UP", "NULL"))
colnames(dt)[ncols:ncol(dt)] = paste0("M", colnames(dt)[ncols:ncol(dt)])
```

result:

```
   M1 M2 M3  UCL  MM1 MM2 MM3
1   1  2  3  1.5 NULL  UP  UP
```

Comment: can you edit your answer so MUCL is instead UCL as in the OP?