# dplyr mutate new dynamic variables with case_when

Tags: r, dynamic, dplyr

I'm aware of similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003574/dplyr-mutate-use-dynamic-variable-names) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340180/automatically-generate-new-variable-names-using-dplyr-mutate), but I haven't been able to figure out the right solution for my specific situation. Some of what I'm finding are solutions which use `mutate_`, etc but I understand these are now obsolete. I'm new to dynamic usages of dplyr.

I have a dataframe which includes some variables with two different prefixes, alpha and beta:

```
df <- data.frame(alpha.num = c(1, 3, 5, 7),
             alpha.char = c("a", "c", "e", "g"),
             beta.num = c(2, 4, 6, 8),
             beta.char = c("b", "d", "f", "h"),
             which.to.use = c("alpha", "alpha", "beta", "beta"))
```

I want to create new variables with the prefix "chosen." which are copies of either the "alpha" or "beta" columns depending on which is named for that row in the "which.to.use" column. The desired output would be:

```
desired.df <- data.frame(alpha.num = c(1, 3, 5, 7),
                     alpha.char = c("a", "c", "e", "g"),
                     beta.num = c(2, 4, 6, 8),
                     beta.char = c("b", "d", "f", "h"),
                     which.to.use = c("alpha", "alpha", "beta", "beta"),
                     chosen.num = c(1, 3, 6, 8),
                     chosen.char = c("a", "c", "f", "h"))
```

My failed attempt:

```
varnames <- c("num", "char")
df %<>%
  mutate(as.name(paste0("chosen.", varnames)) := case_when(
    which.to.use == "alpha" ~ paste0("alpha.", varnames),
    which.to.use == "beta" ~ pasteo("beta.", varnames)
  ))
```

I'd prefer a pure dplyr solution, and even better would be one which could be included in a longer pipe modifying the df (i.e. no need to stop to create "varnames"). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a `nest()/map()` strategy that should be pretty fast. It stays in the `tidyverse`, but doesn't go into `rlang` land.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
    nest(-which.to.use) %>%
    mutate(new_data = map2(data, which.to.use,
                       ~ select(..1, matches(..2)) %>%
                           rename_all(funs(gsub(".*\\.", "choosen.", .) )))) %>%
    unnest()

  which.to.use alpha.num alpha.char beta.num beta.char choosen.num choosen.char
1        alpha         1          a        2         b           1            a
2        alpha         3          c        4         d           3            c
3         beta         5          e        6         f           6            f
4         beta         7          g        8         h           8            h
```

It grabs all columns, not just `num` and `char`, that are not `which.to.use`. But that seems like what you (I) would want IRL. You could add a `select(matches('(var1|var2|etc'))` line before you call `nest()` if you wanted to pull only specific variables.

EDIT:
My original suggestion of using `select()` to drop unneeded columns would result in doing a `join` to bring them back later. If instead you adjust the `nest` parameters, you can acheive this on only certain columns.

I added new `bool` columns here, but they will be ignored for the "choosen" selection:

```
new_df <- data.frame(alpha.num = c(1, 3, 5, 7),
                 alpha.char = c("a", "c", "e", "g"),
                 alpha.bool = FALSE,
                 beta.num = c(2, 4, 6, 8),
                 beta.char = c("b", "d", "f", "h"),
                 beta.bool = TRUE,
                 which.to.use = c("alpha", "alpha", "beta", "beta"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

new_df %>% 
    nest(matches("num|char")) %>% # only columns that match this pattern get nested, allows you to save others
    mutate(new_data = map2(data, which.to.use,
                           ~ select(..1, matches(..2)) %>%
                               rename_all(funs(gsub(".*\\.", "choosen.", .) )))) %>%
    unnest()

  alpha.bool beta.bool which.to.use alpha.num alpha.char beta.num beta.char choosen.num choosen.char
1      FALSE      TRUE        alpha         1          a        2         b           1            a
2      FALSE      TRUE        alpha         3          c        4         d           3            c
3      FALSE      TRUE         beta         5          e        6         f           6            f
4      FALSE      TRUE         beta         7          g        8         h           8            h
```

Comment: I only want to do this on specific variables. Adding a select statement would reduce the df, so I'd have to do a join later to bring back the other variables (if I understand correctly). There must be a better way, right?

Comment: I made an edit to show a better way with just adjusting the `nest()` parameters, let me know if that's what you had in mind

Comment: Awesome! Works great. I don't quite understand everything going on here, but that's homework for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Using some fun `rlang` stuff & `purrr`:

```
library(rlang)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(alpha.num = c(1, 3, 5, 7),
                 alpha.char = c("a", "c", "e", "g"),
                 beta.num = c(2, 4, 6, 8),
                 beta.char = c("b", "d", "f", "h"),
                 which.to.use = c("alpha", "alpha", "beta", "beta"),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

c("num", "char") %>% 
    map(~ mutate(df, !!sym(paste0("chosen.", .x)) := 
      case_when(
          which.to.use == "alpha" ~ !!sym(paste0("alpha.", .x)),
          which.to.use == "beta" ~ !!sym(paste0("beta.", .x))
                ))) %>% 
    reduce(full_join)
```

Result:

```
  alpha.num alpha.char beta.num beta.char which.to.use chosen.num chosen.char
1         1          a        2         b        alpha          1           a
2         3          c        4         d        alpha          3           c
3         5          e        6         f         beta          6           f
4         7          g        8         h         beta          8           h
```

Without `reduce(full_join)`:

```
c("num", "char") %>% 
  map_dfc(~ mutate(df, !!sym(paste0("chosen.", .x)) := 
                 case_when(
                   which.to.use == "alpha" ~ !!sym(paste0("alpha.", .x)),
                   which.to.use == "beta" ~ !!sym(paste0("beta.", .x))
                 ))) %>% 
  select(-ends_with("1"))



alpha.num alpha.char beta.num beta.char which.to.use chosen.num chosen.char
1         1          a        2         b        alpha          1           a
2         3          c        4         d        alpha          3           c
3         5          e        6         f         beta          6           f
4         7          g        8         h         beta          8           h
```

Explanation:
(Note: I do not *fully* or even *kind of* get `rlang`. Maybe others can give a better explanation ;).)

Using `paste0` by itself produces a string, when we need a bare name for `mutate` to know it is referring to a variable name.

If we wrap `paste0` in `sym`, it evaluates to a bare name:

```
> x <- varrnames[1]
> sym(paste0("alpha.", x))
  alpha.num
```

But `mutate` does not know to evaluate and instead read it as a symbol:

```
> typeof(sym(paste0("alpha.", x)))
[1] "symbol"
```

The "bang bang" `!!` operator evaluates the `sym` function. Compare:

```
> expr(mutate(df, var = sym(paste0("alpha.", x))))
mutate(df, var = sym(paste0("alpha.", x)))

> expr(mutate(df, var = !!sym(paste0("alpha.", x))))
mutate(df, var = alpha.num)
```

So with `!!sym` we can use paste to dynamically called variable names with dplyr.

Comment: Thanks. My actual data are very large (both tall and wide), and the full_join brings things to a halt... I'm wondering if there's a way to do it using mutate_at or mutate_if...

Comment: check out my `nest()/map()` answer for a faster `tidyverse` option

Comment: @Nate nice. Using `map_dfc` lets you get rid of the `full_join`.

Answer (score 2):

A base R approach using `apply` with `margin = 1` where we select columns for each row based on the value in `which.to.use` column and get the value from corresponding column for the row.

```
df[c("chosen.num", "chosen.char")] <- 
          t(apply(df, 1, function(x) x[grepl(x["which.to.use"], names(df))]))

df
#  alpha.num alpha.char beta.num beta.char which.to.use chosen.num chosen.char
#1         1          a        2         b        alpha          1           a
#2         3          c        4         d        alpha          3           c
#3         5          e        6         f         beta          6           f
#4         7          g        8         h         beta          8           h
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try a `gather`/`spread` approach

```
df %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  gather(k,v,-which.to.use,-rowname) %>% 
  separate(k,into = c("k1", "k2"), sep="[.]") %>% 
  filter(which.to.use == k1) %>% 
  mutate(k1="chosen") %>% 
  unite(k, k1, k2,sep=".") %>% 
  spread(k,v) %>%
  select(.,chosen.num, chosen.char) %>% 
  bind_cols(df, .)
    alpha.num alpha.char beta.num beta.char which.to.use chosen.num chosen.char
 1         1          a        2         b        alpha          1           a
 2         3          c        4         d        alpha          3           c
 3         5          e        6         f         beta          6           f
 4         7          g        8         h         beta          8           h
```