# Use ifelse inside case_when as function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to put `ifelse` opart inside `dplyr` `case_when` function:

```
library(mutate)

data(mtcars)

mtcars %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(myVar = case_when(
    mpg > 20 ~ ifelse(cyl == 6, 1, NA_real_),
    TRUE ~ 2
  ))
```

into it's own function:

```
myFun <- function(x) {
  ifelse(cyl == x, 1, NA_real_)
}

mtcars %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(myVar = case_when(
    mpg > 20 ~ myFun(6),
    TRUE ~ 2
  ))
```

But it returns an error:

```
Error in ifelse(cyl == x, 1, NA_real_) : object 'cyl' not found
```

How should I rewrite the function to make it work?

Comment: There is no `mutate` package. Please use `reprex`!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass dynamic column names in dplyr into custom function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678435/how-to-pass-dynamic-column-names-in-dplyr-into-custom-function)

Comment: This all definitely has to do with Tidyverse's non-standard evaluation (NSE); see https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html. MyFun is not being executed within the scope of the black magic that converts the column names in the syntax into pointers to the data frame's columns, and I couldn't figure out how to get it to. Is there no better approach than that, though? Executing a function with NSE baked into it?

Comment: Better reference: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html