# R function in shiny doesn't work with an input in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, r-caret

so i have the next chunk of code on my shiny app:

```
observeEvent(input$change_type_btn,{
    req(input$var_cambio)
    
    selected_column <- input$var_cambio

    data(data() %>% mutate(Age = as.numeric(Age)))

  })
```

As you can see, y have a dataframe called data() and I want to change the type of a column into numeric.
as an example I use the column Age which is stored as a char type. This works perfectly.

But the moment I have a SelectInput where I want to select the column to swap like this:

```
selectInput(
          "var_cambio",
          label = "Selecciona la variable a cambiar de tipo:",
          choices = c(names(data())),
          multiple = FALSE,
          selected = NULL
        ),
```

and swap Age with input$var_cambio, the app closes instantly after executing It, returning a "Error in sourceUTF8(serverR, envir = new.env(parent = sharedEnv)) : Error sourcing C:/......./server.R

It's been hours, tried a lot of different things and i'm at my limit, I'm 99% sure It's because inputs should be used in another way or I'm missing something crucial about the topic I haven't learnt yet

i tried multiple ways to use the input by storing It as an auxiliar variable but It did not work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678435/how-to-pass-dynamic-column-names-in-dplyr-into-custom-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help? It might have something to do with 'mutate' not receiving the correct column name from your input.

```
observeEvent(input$change_type_btn, {
  # Ensure that a column has been selected
  req(input$var_cambio)
  
  # Convert the selected column name from string to a symbol
  selected_column <- rlang::sym(input$var_cambio)
  
  # Mutate the selected column to numeric, using non-standard evaluation
  data <- data() %> %> mutate(!!selected_column := as.numeric(.[[selected_column]]))
})
```

Comment: Ok, It ended up working with a mix of both, resulting in :

observeEvent(input$change_type_btn,{
    req(input$var_cambio)

    data(data() %>% mutate(!!input$var_cambio := as.numeric(.[[input$var_cambio]])))

  })

Could you explan me what's the meaning and difference between them? (the double !!, the := and the double brackets [[]]

Comment: The := in dplyr is used for creating new columns with names that aren't known in advance. The !! operator is used to tell dplyr to use the actual value of the variable right now in the code, and .[] accesses the content of the variable treated as a list. So, we're assigning a new value to a dynamically named column. Is that more clear?