# dplyr - Dynamic Variable Names in a loop

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with a set of accounts and their associated usage figures:

`account    usage    Date
1            5       1/1/2015
1           10       1/2/2015
2            8       1/1/2015
2           20       1/2/2015
3           15       1/1/2015
3           12       1/2/2015`

I am trying to use dplyr to lag the usage by 1 day,2 days, 3 days, etc...up to 12, and create a column for each lag called lag.usage1, lag.usage2, etc...

I have tried

```
for(i=2:12){
df<-df%.%group_by(account)%.%mutate(lag.usage[i]=lag(usage,i))}
```

as well as

```
 for(i in 2:12){
  varname <- paste("lag.usage", i , sep="")
  df<-df%.%group_by(account)%.%mutate(varname=lag(usage, i))}
```

Both error out *Error: unexpected '='*

Can anyone suggest a workaround to resolve this issue using the dplyr framework?

Comment: Maybe if you put in in parentheses, like `mutate((varname)=lag(usage,i))`?

Comment: Oh, it looks like this is the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003574/r-dplyr-mutate-use-dynamic-variable-names