# Using dplyr in assignment

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I have a question about `dplyr`.

Lets say I want to update certain values in a dataframe, can I do this?:

```
mtcars %>% filter(mpg>20) %>% select(hp)=1000
```

(The example is nonsensical where all cars with MPGs greater than 20 have HP set to 1000)

I get an error so I am guessing the answer is no I can't use `%>%` and the `dplyr` verbs to the left of an assignment, but the `dplyr` syntax is a lot cleaner than:

```
mtcars[mtcars$mpg>20,"hp"]=1000
```

Especially when you are dealing with more complex cases, so I wanted to ask if there is any way to use the `dplyr` syntax in this case?

edit: It looks like `mutate` is the verb I want, so now my question is, can I dynamically change the name of the var in the mutate statement like so:

```
for (i in c("hp","wt")) {mtcars<-mtcars %>% filter(mpg>20) %>% mutate(i=1000) }
```

This example just creates a column named "i" with value 1000, which isn't what I want.

Comment: Do you want `mtcars %>% mutate(hp = ifelse(mpg>20, 1000, hp))`?

Comment: mutate(mtcars,hp=ifelse(mpg>20,1000,hp)

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick

Comment: In vanilla R, you can do things like `x[ y > 20 ] <- 1000`, but dplyr doesn't support it. If you're interested in trying yet another package, this is doable in data.table: `DT <- data.table(mtcars); DT[mpg > 20, hp := 1000]`

Comment: Can I change the name of the new var in the mutate statement dynamically?

Comment: I think this might answer that question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26003574/1191259