# How to create a dynamic number and name of mutate calls in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, lazy-evaluation

I am making a dynamic permutation function to create order independent parameters. Outside of a function, I have been able to hard code this approach with dplyr. However, I want to generalize it so that I could use the same function to permute 3 factors or 6 factors without typing all of the repeating calls. However, I have not figured out how to make it work.

Here's a simple data frame `df` of all the permutations of 3 variables:

```
#> dput(df)
structure(list(var1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c"), class = "factor"), var2 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), var3 =     structure(c(3L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), 
    X1 = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.8, 0.8, 0.3, 0.3), X2 = c(0.8, 0.3, 0.5, 
    0.3, 0.5, 0.8), X3 = c(0.3, 0.8, 0.3, 0.5, 0.8, 0.5)), .Names = c("var1", 
"var2", "var3", "X1", "X2", "X3"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

My goal is to get to the average order independent value of each variable. To get there, I need to create two intermediate variables: one a multiplication `m1, m2, m3, m4` and one a subtraction `s1, s2, s3, s4`. The variables `m1` and `s1` are special, `m1 = X1`, and `s1 = X1-1`. However, the others need to refer to the one before: `m2 = X2*X1` and `s2 = m2-m1`.

I tried to combine the ideas from this SO question: [R - dplyr - mutate - use dynamic variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003574/r-dplyr-mutate-use-dynamic-variable-names) with a lazyeval interp, so that I could dynamically refer to the other variables and also dynamically name mutated columns. However, it only kept the last one sent, and the rename did not work, so I got a single additional column, named, for example, `X2*X3`, which is fine on this example with 3. When I had 5, it gave a single additional column `X4*X5`.

```
for(n in 2:n_params) {
     varname <- paste("m", n, sep=".")
     df <- mutate_(df, .dots = setNames(interp(~one*two, one=as.name(paste0("X",n-1)),
                                               two=as.name(paste0("X",n))),varname))
     df
   }
```

Since I can not figure out why this does not work, I have set up a series of if statements that calculate the `m`s and `s`s .

```
 xx <- data.frame(df) %>%
     mutate(m1 = X1,
            s1 = X1 - 1)
   if(n_params >= 2) {
     xx <- data.frame(xx) %>%
       mutate(m2 = m1 * X2,
              s2 = m2 - m1)
   }
   if(n_params >= 3) {
     xx <- data.frame(xx) %>%
       mutate(m3 = m2 * X3,
              s3 = m3 - m2)
   }
   if(n_params >= 4) {
     xx <- data.frame(xx) %>%
       mutate(m4 = m3 * X4,
              s4 = m4 - m3)
   }
   if(n_params >= 5) {
     xx <- data.frame(xx) %>%
       mutate(m5 = m4 * X5,
         s5 = m5 - m4)
   }
   if(n_params >= 6) {
     xx <- data.frame(xx) %>%
       mutate(m6 = m5 * X6,
              s6 = m6 - m5)
   }
```

It seems like I should be able to write a function that creates this,

In pseudocode:

```
function(n_params) {
 function(x) {
   new_df <- df %>% 
            mutate(m1 = X1,
                  s1 = X1 - 1)
   for(i in 2:n_params){
    new_df <- append(call to new_df, 
             mutate(mi = Xi*Xi-1,
                   si = mi-mi-1)
     }
   }
}
```

However, I cannot figure out how to combine the `lazyeval interp` and the setNames to allow for referring to the previous mutated value.

I could just leave it in if functions, but I'd love to make this more compact if possible.

The final final output of interest is the average s value over all permutations for each initial variable. I do that in a separate function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the prettiest thing, but it works:

```
n_params = 3

xx1 = df %>%
mutate(m1 = X1,
       s1 = X1 - 1)

for (i in 2:n_params) {
xx1 = xx1 %>%
    mutate_(.dots = setNames(list(varval = paste0("m", i - 1, " * X", i)),
                             paste0("m", i))) %>%
    mutate_(.dots = setNames(list(varval = paste0("m", i, " - m", i - 1)),
                             paste0("s", i)))
}
```

There's probably *much* better ways to use `lazyeval`. Hopefully someone else will show a nice answer, but this does match the `xx` produced in your question (for `n_params = 3`):

```
identical(xx, xx1)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: I think I may have a version issue. If I try this, xx1 does create m2 and s2, but when it tries to create m3, it cannot find m2. error `Error: object 'm2' not found ` I'm running: R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) with  lazyeval_0.1.10 dplyr_0.4.3 ; the error refers to Rcpp, and that is Rcpp_0.12.1. `stop(structure(list(message = "object 'm2' not found", call = NULL, 
    cppstack = NULL), .Names = c("message", "call", "cppstack"
), class = c("Rcpp::eval_error", "C++Error", "error", "condition"
))) `

Comment: My Rcpp version is 0.12.2, but otherwise we match.

Comment: My error, I had `xx1 = xx %>%` - that would never work.  Thanks for solving this.                 *my big question* I wonder why `list` works and saves the values and names but `interp` did not.

Comment: I just went off the question you linked... the `setNames(list())` idiom is used there, even when `interp` is also used. I would only expect `interp` to help simplify the variable name construction and clean up some of the `paste`ing.

Comment: maybe all along, my mistake was dropping `list()` Thanks.