# Using dplyr::mutate to apply parameterizations of a function to a single data frame column, then save the results to new columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Let's say I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
user_id  date          weight
12345    2016-03-07    160
12345    2016-03-06    158
12345    2016-03-05    156
12345    2016-03-04    154
```

I would like to mutate this data frame by applying multiple functions to the `weight` column, then saving the results of each application to a new column. The one caveat is that this function is parameterized, and I'd like to append the parameter value to the new column name. For example, if I use `lag()`:

```
user_id  date          weight    dweight_1    dweight_2    ...
12345    2016-03-07    160       NA           NA   
12345    2016-03-06    158       160          NA
12345    2016-03-05    156       158          160
12345    2016-03-04    154       156          158
```

where the first new column is the result of `lag(weight, 1)`, the second from `lag(weight, 2)`, and so on.

I tried following the standard evaluation approach proposed in dplyr's vignette on the subject, as well as suggestions from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003574/r-dplyr-mutate-use-dynamic-variable-names), but neither seem to address the wrinkle of a parameterized function (otherwise I'd just use `funs()`!).

How can I tackle this problem?

Comment: You can do this is pretty easily using `library(data.table) ; setDT(DT)[, paste0("weight_", 1L:nrow(DT)) := shift(weight, 1L:.N)]` for instance.

Comment: @lukeA Your code did not work for me.

Comment: @DavidArenburg This is a helpful solution and a reminder of how concise `data.table` solutions can be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a single column programmatically with `dplyr`, you could use something like

```
x <- 2
mutate_(df, .dots = setNames(list(~lag(weight, x)), paste0('dweight_', x)))
```

You could repeat that if it's just a couple times (even chain them together if you like), but if you're doing this a lot, it may make sense to write a function:

```
dweight <- function(l = 1){
  for (i in l){
    df <- mutate_(df, .dots = setNames(list(~lag(weight, i)), paste0('dweight_', i)))
  }
  df
}
```

which you can pass a vector:

```
> dweight(1:4)
  user_id       date weight dweight_1 dweight_2 dweight_3 dweight_4
1   12345 2016-03-07    160        NA        NA        NA        NA
2   12345 2016-03-06    158       160        NA        NA        NA
3   12345 2016-03-05    156       158       160        NA        NA
4   12345 2016-03-04    154       156       158       160        NA
```

You can edit that function as you like: add a dataframe parameter so you can chain it, use `*apply` instead of `for`, add a parameter to pass a function, etc. Go wild.

Comment: This is great, thanks! I was hoping to avoid a loop, but this reads easily while providing flexibility like you suggested.

Comment: As loops go, this one is pretty benign because it's vectorized (not building a column element by element); it only runs four times in the example. If you'd rather, you could rewrite it to use an `*apply` function, preallocate, etc. Unless you're adding a huge number of columns, the time difference probably won't be significant, though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that should work (there may be a cleaner way though)

```
# Assuming lag_vals is set as follows
lag_vals <- 1:3
names(lag_vals) <- paste0('dweight_', 1:3)

df_new <- cbind(df, sapply(lag_vals, function(x) { x=lag(df$weight, x) }))
df_new
##   user_id       date weight dweight_1 dweight_2 dweight_3
## 1   12345 2016-03-07    160        NA        NA        NA
## 2   12345 2016-03-06    158       160        NA        NA
## 3   12345 2016-03-05    156       158       160        NA
## 4   12345 2016-03-04    154       156       158       160
```

Answer (score 1):

dplyr::mutate solution with standard evaluation:

```
tab %>% mutate_(.dots = setNames(lapply(1:4, function(i) lazyeval::interp(~lag(weight, i),
        weight = as.name("weight"))), paste0("weight_", 1:4)))
#   user_id       date weight weight_1 weight_2 weight_3 weight_4
# 1   12345 2016-03-07    160       NA       NA       NA       NA
# 2   12345 2016-03-06    158      160       NA       NA       NA
# 3   12345 2016-03-05    156      158      160       NA       NA
# 4   12345 2016-03-04    154      156      158      160       NA
```

Edit: this is a bit tidier...

```
lags = 3
lag_weight <- function(i) lazyeval::interp(~lag(weight, i), weight = as.name("weight"))
tab %>% mutate_(.dots = setNames(lapply(1:lags, lag_weight), paste0('weight_', 1:lags)))
#   user_id       date weight weight_1 weight_2 weight_3 weight_4
# 1   12345 2016-03-07    160       NA       NA       NA       NA
# 2   12345 2016-03-06    158      160       NA       NA       NA
# 3   12345 2016-03-05    156      158      160       NA       NA
# 4   12345 2016-03-04    154      156      158      160       NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tidyquant::tq_mutate` to solve this problem.
Here is a toy example.

```
# Get Stock Prices from Yahoo! Finance

# Create a vector of stock symbols
FANG_symbols <- c("FB", "AMZN", "NFLX", "GOOG")

# Pass symbols to tq_get to get daily prices
FANG_data_d <- FANG_symbols %>%
    tq_get(get = "stock.prices", from = "2014-01-01", to = "2016-12-31")

# Show the result
FANG_data_d

FANG_data_d %>%
    select(symbol, date, adjusted) %>%
    group_by(symbol) %>%
    tq_mutate(
        select     = adjusted,
        mutate_fun = lag.xts,
        k          = 1:5,
        col_rename = column_names
    )
```

**Reference**

Dancho, Matt. 2017. “Demo Week: Class(Monday) <- Tidyquant.” http://www.business-science.io/code-tools/2017/10/23/demo_week_tidyquant.html.