# Using lead/lag in a Shiny App

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, dplyr

I feel like this question applies to a general query about how to manipulate  data within a Shiny context but my specific question relates to the usage of the lead/lag functions in `dplyr`. Right now I am faced with two problems.

The first problem is defining the variables in the dataset that have been `lead/lag`. I am using a `dplyr` approach where I name the lagged variable `yvar`. CLearly this isn't correct as R isn't able to find `yvar`. So can anyone recommend a way to change/create a variable so that the result is transferred down through the shiny app and available to be called?

The second problem is specifying the number of rows to lead/lag the Y variable. It is easy enough in the ui.R file to specify an input box with lead/lag positions. But then how do I place the integer from that input box as an argument in the `lead` function?

Here is the **ui.R**:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


dataset <- iris

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Iris Data Explorer"),

  sidebarPanel(


    selectInput('x', 'X', names(dataset), names(dataset)[[2]]),
    selectInput('y', 'Y', names(dataset), names(dataset)[[4]]),
    selectInput('offset', 'Offset Level of Y', 0:5, 0),
    selectInput('species', 'Species', levels(dataset$Species), "virginica")
  ),

  mainPanel(
    plotOutput('plot')
  )
))
```

And here is the **server.R**:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  dataset <- reactive({
    iris %>%
      filter(Species==input$species) 
    #%>% mutate(yvar=lead(input$y, paste0(input$offset)))
  })



  output$plot <- renderPlot({


    dataset<-dataset()
    p <- ggplot(dataset, aes_string(x=input$x,
                                    #y=yvar)
                                    y=input$y
    )) +
      geom_point() 

    print(p)

  }, height=500)

})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want. To get it to work I did the following:

- abandoned `mutate` because it apparently is quite difficult to use dynamic names with it (see:[R - dplyr - mutate - use dynamic variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003574/r-dplyr-mutate-use-dynamic-variable-names)) and just did it with data frame indexing as suggested there.
- combined it into one file so I can see everything at once (good for small stuff)
- added a `print` statement to dump the dataset on every change so you can see what is happening.
- added quotes to the `yvar` variable so that it works with `aesstring`
- added an `as.numeric` to the offset variable as an input to `lead`

This is the resulting code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

dataset <- iris

u <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Iris Data Explorer"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput('x', 'X', names(dataset), names(dataset)[[2]]),
    selectInput('y', 'Y', names(dataset), names(dataset)[[4]]),
    selectInput('offset', 'Offset Level of Y', 0:5, 0),
    selectInput('species', 'Species', levels(dataset$Species), "virginica")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput('plot')
  )
))
s <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  dataset <- reactive({
    df <- iris %>% filter(Species==input$species) 
    df[["yvar"]] <- lead(df[[input$y]],as.numeric(input$offset))
    return(df)
  })
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    dataset<-dataset()
    print(dataset)
    ggplot(dataset, aes_string(x=input$x,y="yvar")) + geom_point(na.rm=T) 
  }, height=500)
})
shinyApp(ui=u,server=s)
```

And this is what it looks like:
[image]

Comment: Actually using `mutate` with dynamic names is trivial — just switch to `mutate_` and provide a named vector with the transformations.

Comment: Then that link (that Hadley was on) is obsolete? So how should it look? Your description is too brief for me.

Comment: Not obsolete, just incomplete. OP’ code, using `mutate_`, would look as follows: `mutate_(yvar = bquote(lead(.(as.name(y)), .(as.numeric(offset)))))` — in general, just pass an expression or formula, with the desired names injected. I myself am partial to `bquote` but dplyr also comes with `lazyeval` which makes constructing these expressions handy (shown in the linked answer).

Comment: Thanks. The OP can decide to use that if they want. Someone (you perhaps?) maybe needs to add a new answer to that other post as well.

Comment: I think it is probably best to go with the answer provided by here. `lazyeval` can be a bit confusing. Just so I understand thought `input$x` doesn't need quotes in `aes_string` because it is already a string? That is the format here?