# Unable to dynamically add variable names to a dataframe in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm looking to tack on a bunch of variables to an existing dataframe, based on another dataframe. I was using this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003574/r-dplyr-mutate-use-dynamic-variable-names) to set myself up, but it's not actually doing anything.

Let's say in the code below I have a dataframe named `comp`, and I want to add to the dataframe `iris` empty variables by iteratively going through each column in `comp` and naming that variable by the first row in the column "vs" the second row in that column:

```
library(tidyverse)
comp <- as_tibble(combn(letters[1:4], 2))
mydf <- as_tibble(iris)

# Creating a function that creates a variable name for each column in comp
# and creates a variable with that name in df
varname_assign <- function(df, n){
varname <- paste0(comp[[1,n]], "Vs", comp[[2,n]])
mutate_(df, .dots= setNames(list(NA), varname))
return(df)
}

for (i in seq_along(comp)) {
mydf <- varname_assign(mydf, i)
}

mydf

# A tibble: 150 × 5
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
      <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>  <fctr>
1      5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa

#Nothing happened :(
```

I'm trying to get something like this:

```
# A tibble: 150 × 11
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species  AvsB  AvsC  AvsD  BvsC  BvsD  CvsD
      <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>  <fctr>  <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1      5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

EDIT: sigh. I just realized `return(df)` in the function is the culprit. If I remove that line, it all works. Not sure what the logic is behind that, though.

Comment: You don't assign the return value of `mutate_`.

Comment: Your `mutate_` call wasn't assigning a result to anything, so it created new variables and then they just vanished, followed by you telling the function to explicitly return the _original_ `df`. If you had done `df <- mutate_(...)` it probably would have worked as you expected, with the `return()` call.

Comment: Evidently, I need more coffee before posting bad questions.

Comment: You can never go wrong with more coffee.