# R: looping through column names

Tags: r, dplyr

I am a Stata user trying to switch to R and having the usual beginner's struggle. I have been trying (and failing) to do a loop for a few days and I now surrender. 
What I want to do (in a loop):

- start from a list of variable names
- create a new variable
- recode that new variable(s) based on the value of existing variables
- possibly do so using the dplyr syntax, but this is not essential,
  only for consistency with the rest of my code.

Here is a stylised example of what I am trying to do. In my actual data, the x.x and x.y variables originate from the join function applied to 2 existing data frames.

```
N <- 1000
  df  <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(N),
x2.x = rnorm(N)+2,x2.y = rnorm(N)-2,
x3.x = rnorm(N)+3,x3.y = rnorm(N)-3)

varlist <- c("x2","x3")
lapply(varlist, function(x) {
   df <- df %>% mutate(x = ifelse(x1 < 0, paste0(x,".y"),paste0(x,".x")) # generate varialble "x" values from existing x.x and x.y
  })
```

When I run the lapply part of the code I get the error message

> Error: unexpected '}' in:
>   "   df <- df %>% mutate(x = ifelse(x1 < 0, paste0(x,".y"),paste0(x,".x")) # generate varialble "x" values from existing x.x and x.y
>     }"

even though it should be expected... I am sure there a number of mistakes in my code, and that's partly because I am used to macros in Stata for which there is no direct equivalent in R. Anyway, if you can point me in the right direction it would be fantastic!

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket at the end of the `mutate( ... )` call. That is, you have 4x `(` and only 3x `)`

Comment: The error message is telling you the `}` is unexpected; it's not where it should be.

Comment: Are you after something like `df$x2 <- ifelse(df$x1 < 0, df$x2.y, df$x2.x)` ?

Comment: yes exactly. but using a loop and possibly using the dplyr syntax

Comment: Do you absolutely *have* to use a loop? when a simple `df[, varlist] <- c(ifelse(df$x1 < 0, df$x2.y, df$x2.x), ifelse(df$x1 < 0, df$x3.y, df$x3.x))` will do the job?

Comment: Hi SymbolixAU, this is just an example of what I am trying to do, but in reality I have more than just two variables and so I am trying to use a loop. I have read about the for function, and lapply, but I keep writing bad code so I'd like to learn the right syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is that your `paste0(x, ".y")` is literally pasting the `x` with `.y`. And that's it, you're not telling it to subset the data by that column.

What you actually should be doing is subsetting the data according to the column name that's generated by `paste0(x, ".y")`. So for example, to get the column of data `x2.y` you can go

```
df[, paste0(varlist[1], ".y")]
## and of course the same can be done for second item of varlist
# df[, paste0(varlist[2], ".y")]
```

Now we know how to subset columns by a variable name, and because you want to learn how to write it in a loop, we can replace the numbers in `varlist[1]` (and `varlist[2]`) with a 'looping' variable

Here are two ways to do it, one using a **for** loop, and the other using **sapply**

#### For loop

```
for(i in varlist){
  df[, i] <- ifelse(df[, "x1"] < 0, df[, paste0(i, ".y")], df[, paste0(i, ".x")])
}

head(df)
#            x1       x2.x       x2.y     x3.x       x3.y         x2        x3
# 1 -0.56047565  1.0042013 -2.5116037 2.849693 -2.8034502 -2.5116037 -2.803450
# 2 -0.23017749  0.9600450 -1.7630621 2.672243 -2.3498868 -1.7630621 -2.349887
# 3  1.55870831  1.9820198 -2.5415892 1.551835 -2.3289958  1.9820198  1.551835
# 4  0.07050839  1.8678249 -0.7807724 2.302715 -4.2841578  1.8678249  2.302715
# 5  0.12928774 -0.5493428 -1.8258641 5.598490 -5.0261096 -0.5493428  5.598490
# 6  1.71506499  3.0405735 -2.6152683 2.962585 -0.7946739  3.0405735  2.962585
```

#### sapply

You can also do this using an `*apply`, and in this instance I'm using `sapply` so that it 'simplifies' the result (whereas an `lapply` would return lists)

```
df[, varlist] <- sapply(varlist, function(x){
   ifelse(df[, "x1"] < 0, df[, paste0(x, ".y")], df[, paste0(x, ".x")])
})

head(df)
#            x1       x2.x       x2.y     x3.x       x3.y         x2        x3
# 1 -0.56047565  1.0042013 -2.5116037 2.849693 -2.8034502 -2.5116037 -2.803450
# 2 -0.23017749  0.9600450 -1.7630621 2.672243 -2.3498868 -1.7630621 -2.349887
# 3  1.55870831  1.9820198 -2.5415892 1.551835 -2.3289958  1.9820198  1.551835
# 4  0.07050839  1.8678249 -0.7807724 2.302715 -4.2841578  1.8678249  2.302715
# 5  0.12928774 -0.5493428 -1.8258641 5.598490 -5.0261096 -0.5493428  5.598490
# 6  1.71506499  3.0405735 -2.6152683 2.962585 -0.7946739  3.0405735  2.962585
```

---

#### Data

```
set.seed(123)   ## setting the seed as we're sampling
N <- 1000
df  <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(N),
                  x2.x = rnorm(N)+2,x2.y = rnorm(N)-2,
                  x3.x = rnorm(N)+3,x3.y = rnorm(N)-3)
```

Comment: thanks! your code works beautifully. I know this is a bit demanding, but would you know how to do the same thing using dplyr syntax?

Comment: I tried the following code: 
    set.seed(123)   ## setting the seed as we're sampling
N <- 1000
df  <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(N),
                  x2.x = rnorm(N)+2,x2.y = rnorm(N)-2,
                  x3.x = rnorm(N)+3,x3.y = rnorm(N)-3)
df[, varlist]  <- sapply(varlist, function(x) 
  df %>% mutate_(x = ifelse("x1" < 0, paste0(x,".y"),paste0(x,".x")) 
  ))
head(df)

but then I get something really strange. The newly created x2 variable is equal to x1 (instead of x2.x), while newly created x3 variable is equal to x2.x (instead of x3.x)

Comment: @mariodrumblue I've never liked using `dplyr` syntax in a loop, particularly when using dynamically created variable names. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26003574/5977215) for an example of why I avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

try this brother

replace `mutate` by `mutate_`

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html

Comment: thanks! I tried and it almost gave me what I am after, except  I get i) a new variable named x (while it should be x2 or x3 depending on the value of x in the loop) and ii) while I can see the printed output on the console, the df data frame is still unchanged. What am I missing? This the code:

Comment: lapply(varlist, function(x) 
        df <- df %>% 
          mutate_(x = ifelse("x1" < 0, paste0(x,".y"),paste0(x,".x")) 
    ))
    head(df)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
lapply(varlist, function(x) 
  df <- df %>% mutate(x = ifelse(x1 < 0, paste0(x,".y"),paste0(x,".x")) # generate varialble "x" values from existing x.x and x.y
))
```

You do not need the braces to designate a loop using `lapply`. [Read this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-apply-sapply-lapply-in-r/) for more info on `lapply` syntax.

Comment: thanks. I see the problem. However, I am still not getting what I want:

Comment: thanks. I see the problem. However, I am still not getting what I want: using your code I get i) a new variable named x (while it should be x2 or x3 depending on the value of x in the loop) and ii) the value given to x is x2.x or x2.y (while it should be the numeric value corresponding to those variables), and iii) while I can see the printed output on the console, the df data frame is still unchanged. Any hint? sorry for the many questions. Mario