# looping through column name as object

Tags: r, function, loops

I'm trying to use `loop` through column names in dataframe.

I have a dataset, `testset`, which has about 100 columns. To simplify, I will call these columns in alphabet, `a`, `b`, `c`, ... and so on.

I made `function` to mutate values in `testset` into other value.

```
mutatefun<-function(i){
  i1<-rlang::quo_name(enquo(i))
  output<-testset%>%mutate(!! i1:=case_when({{i}} %in% c(1)~0,
                                   {{i}} %in% c(2)~50,
                                   {{i}} %in% c(3)~100,
                                   TRUE~NA_real_))
  return(output)
  }
```

When i ran `mutatefun(a)`, it worked. Now I want to use this function for multiple columns in `testset`

With help of this post [R: looping through column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41318201/r-looping-through-column-names?rq=1), I created `varlist` and ran this code.

```
varlist<-c("a","c","e","k")

for(i in varlist){
output<-mutatefun({{i}})}
```

However, it didn't return expected results. Instead, it return column `a` as `NA`. I think it might read `i` as only character, not object in `testset`.

Would you let me know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `map_dfc` with `transmute`

```
library(dplyr)

purrr::map_dfc(varlist, ~{
   var <- sym(.x)
   transmute(testset, !!.x := case_when(!!var == 1~0, 
                                        !!var == 2~50, 
                                        !!var == 3~100, 
                                        TRUE~ NA_real_))
})
```

If you want other columns which are not in `varlist`, you may add

```
%>% bind_cols(testset %>% select(-varlist))
```

at the end of the chain.