# Passing a column name to written function which uses dplyr functions

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I have a function that I wrote which is supposed to filter some values and then produce a crosstabulation. It filters the values using the dplyr filter,select commands.

My problem is that when I pass the name of the column ot the function I get an error, and when I pass the name as string with "" around it, it does not filter the observations.
Here is the code:

```
fnDoCrosstab <- function(a) {
  x <- surv_data1 %>% filter(a != "blank") %>% select(a) %>% as.matrix() %>% as.vector()
  y <- surv_data1 %>% filter(a != "blank") %>% select(segment_name) %>% as.matrix() %>% as.vector()
  CrossTable(x,y, format = "SPSS",prop.chisq = F)
}
fnDoCrosstab(b_thisyear)
```

Comment: Suggested dupe: [dplyr mutate with variable column names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26003574/903061)

Comment: Also note that `dplyr` comes [with a vignette on Programming with dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html) which covers how to do this in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the latest version of dplyr (0.7), you can do something like this

```
library(dplyr)

fnDoCrosstab <- function(a) {
  a <- enquo(a)
  x <- mtcars %>% filter((!!a) != 0) %>% select(mpg, !!a) %>% as.vector()
  x
}
fnDoCrosstab(am)
fnDoCrosstab(vs)
```

You capture the unevaluated field name with `enquo()` and then you expand that as necessary with `!!`

Comment: That worked! Although I'm not sure why. What does `enquo()` actually do? And what is the `!!` operator?

Comment: There is all new stuff that `dplyr` (and more specifically `rlang`) has introduced. To learn how to use them read the [programming with dplyr vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html)

Comment: I try to reproduce the same thing with mutate function, but it is not working, do you have an idea why ? `df <- df %>% filter((!!originalvar) > 1) %>% mutate( (!!originalvar) = 99)`

Comment: @M4hd1 if you want to expand on the left side of an equals in mutate, you need to use `:=` rather than `=`. try `mutate( (!!originalvar) := 99)`

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you !