# mutate columns after subsetting by value

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large dataframe and want to standardise multiple columns while conditioning the mean and the standard deviation on values. Say I have the following example data:

```
set.seed(123)
df = data.frame("sample" = c(rep(1:2, each = 5)),
       "status" = c(0,1),
       "s1" = runif(10, -1, 1),
       "s2" = runif(10, -5, 5),
       "s3" = runif(10, -25, 25))
```

and want to standardise every s1-s3 while conditioning the mean and standard deviation to be status==0. If I should do this for say, s1 only I could do the following:

```
df = df %>% group_by(sample) %>%
  mutate(sd_s1 = (s1 - mean(s1[status==0])) / sd(s1[status==0]))
```

But my problem arises when I have to perform this operation on multiple columns. I tried writing a function to include with mutate_at:

```
standardize <- function(x) {
    return((x - mean(x[status==0]))/sd(x[status==0]))
}

df = df %>% group_by(sample) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(s1:s3), standardize)
```

Which just creates Na values for s1-s3. 
I have tried to use the answer provided in:
[R - dplyr - mutate - use dynamic variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003574/r-dplyr-mutate-use-dynamic-variable-names), but cannot figure out how to do the subsetting.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could just use

```
df %>%
  group_by(sample) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(s1:s3), funs((.- mean(.[status == 0]))/sd(.[status == 0])))
```

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. Is there a way to create multiple new columns, such as `sd_s1, sd_s2, ...`, while keep the original columns, such as `s1, s2, ...` using the `mutate_at` function?

Comment: @ycw Thanks, You can use `df %>% group_by(sample) %>% mutate_at(vars(s1:s3), funs(sd = (.- mean(.[status == 0]))/sd(.[status == 0])))`

Comment: This is great. Thanks again.

Comment: @J.Debost  Your code is not working for me.  `df[,3:ncol(df)] %>% mutate_all(standardize)#
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: object 'status' not found.`  What is the version of your dplyr?  I am using 0.7.2.  THe `.` is referring back to the individual columns specified in the `vars`

Comment: I'm so sorry for the confusion! Your code is running just the way it's supposed to, standardising the specified columns by group using only mean and sd in controls (status == 0). Simple and efficient! Thank you very much for your help. I have deleted my two earlier comments.