# dplyr mutate using variable columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, nse, quosure

I am trying to use `mutate` to create a new column with values based on a specific column.

Example final data frame (I am trying to create `new_col`):

```
x = tibble(colA = c(11, 12, 13),
           colB = c(91, 92, 93),
           col_to_use = c("colA", "colA", "colB"),
           new_col = c(11, 12, 93))
```

I would like to do something like:

```
x %>% mutate(new_col = col_to_use)
```

Except instead of column contents, I would like to transform them to a variable. I started with:

```
col_name = "colA"
x %>% mutate(new_col = !!as.name(col_name))
```

That works with a static variable. However, I have been unable to change the variable to represent the column. How do I take a column name based on contents of a different column?

This question is basically the opposite of this: [dplyr - mutate: use dynamic variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003574/dplyr-mutate-use-dynamic-variable-names). I wasn't able to adapt the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 5):

We can use `imap_dbl` and `pluck` from the [purrr](/questions/tagged/purrr) package to achieve this task.

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- tibble(colA = c(11, 12, 13),
           colB = c(91, 92, 93),
           col_to_use = c("colA", "colA", "colB"))

x2 <- x %>%
  mutate(new_col = imap_dbl(col_to_use, ~pluck(x, .x, .y)))

x2
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   colA  colB col_to_use new_col
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>
# 1   11.   91. colA           11.
# 2   12.   92. colA           12.
# 3   13.   93. colB           93.
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how to do it with `tidyverse` idioms alone (though I assume there's a way). But here's a method using `apply`:

```
x$new_col = apply(x, 1, function(d) {
  d[match(d["col_to_use"], names(x))]
})
```

> ```
>   colA colB col_to_use new_col
> 1   11   91       colA      11
> 2   12   92       colA      12
> 3   13   93       colB      93
> ```

Or, putting the `apply` inside `mutate`:

```
x = x %>% 
  mutate(new_col = apply(x, 1, function(d) {
    d[match(d["col_to_use"], names(x))]
  }))
```