# dplyr mutate using dynamic variable name while respecting group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying as per

[dplyr mutate using variable columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49311043/dplyr-mutate-using-variable-columns)
&
[dplyr - mutate: use dynamic variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003574/dplyr-mutate-use-dynamic-variable-names)

to use dynamic names in mutate.  What I am trying to do is to normalize column data by groups subject to a minimum standard deviation.  Each column has a different minimum standard deviation

e.g. (I omitted loops & map statements for convenience)

```
require(dplyr)
require(magrittr)
data(iris)
iris <- tbl_df(iris)

minsd <- c('Sepal.Length' = 0.8)
varname <- 'Sepal.Length'

iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% mutate(!!varname := mean(pluck(iris,varname),na.rm=T)/max(sd(pluck(iris,varname)),minsd[varname]))
```

I got the dynamic assignment & variable selection to work as suggested by the reference answers.  But group_by() is not respected which, for me at least, is the main benefit of using dplyr here

desired answer is given by

```
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% mutate(!!varname := mean(Sepal.Length,na.rm=T)/max(sd(Sepal.Length),minsd[varname]))
```

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I actually did not know much about `pluck`, so I don't know what went wrong, but I would go for this and this works:

```
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(
    !! varname :=
      mean(!!as.name(varname), na.rm = T) / 
      max(sd(!!as.name(varname)),
          minsd[varname])
  )
```

Let me know if this isn't what you were looking for.

Comment: No problem. I'm sorry I can't pinpoint you to what went wrong though. If I figure it out, I'll come back and edit my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The other answer is obviously the best and it also solved a similar problem that I have encountered. For example, with `!!as.name()`, there is no need to use `group_by_()` (or `group_by_at` or `arrange_()` (or `arrange_at()`).

However, another way is to replace `pluck(iris,varname)` in your code with `.data[[varname]]`. The reason why `pluck(iris,varname)` does not work is that, I suppose, `iris` in `pluck(iris,varname)` is not grouped. However, `.data` refer to the `tibble` that executes `mutate()`, and so is grouped.

An alternative to `as.name()` is `rlang::sym()` from the `rlang` package.