# R dplyr: calling `count()` with variable name (now that `count_()` is deprecated)

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use `dplyr`'s `count()` with a dynamic variable name instead of a column name. Before, I would use `count_()`, but this is now deprecated.  What is the best replacement?

Minimal reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(id = 1:10, city = sample(c("London","Paris","Amsterdam"), 10, replace=TRUE))
colname <- "city"
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
df %>% count( city )  # desired output (works but isn't dynamic)
df %>% count( !!colname )  # doesn't work, makes it literally "city"
df %>% count( vars(colname) )  # doesn't work
df %>% count( eval(colname) )  # doesn't work either
df %>% count( eval(parse(text=colname)) )  # works, but is not 'dplyr' ?
df %>% count( eval(sym(colname)) )  # works, but using `sym` from 'rlang'
df %>% count( !!as.name(colname) )  # works, but using `as.name` from 'base'
df %>% count_( colname )  # works, but is deprecated
```

Not sure whether any of the above is the preferred method, or whether it's something altogether different?

Thanks in advance!

PS. I found the `as.name()` solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49913349/1092247).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [development version of `dplyr`](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr), which [will soon be released](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/dplyr-1-0-0-is-coming-soon/) on CRAN as version 1.0, the `across` function seems like the appropriate choice:

```
df %>% count(across(colname))
```

In the current CRAN version of `dplyr`, the `group_by_at()` function can take a string, so you could do:

```
df %>% group_by_at(colname) %>% tally
```

If there were a `count_at` convenience function, the natural analogous thing to do would be:

```
df %>% count_at(colname)
```

But `dplyr` doesn't have a `count_at` function, so that doesn't work.

`group_by_at` can also work with a mixture of strings and names when used with `vars`, so you could do:

```
colname = "cyl"
mtcars %>% group_by_at(vars(colname, vs)) %>% tally
```

`group_by_at` will continue to work in `dplyr` 1.0, so you could create your own `count_at` function if you wish. This will work with strings, names, or even a mixture of the two:

```
count_at = function(data, ...) {
  data %>% group_by_at(vars(...)) %>% tally
}

colname="city"
df %>% count_at(colname)
```

> ```
>   city          n
> * <fct>     <int>
> 1 Amsterdam     3
> 2 London        3
> 3 Paris         4
> ```

```
mtcars %>% count_at("cyl", vs)
```

> ```
>     cyl    vs     n
>   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
> 1     4     0     1
> 2     4     1    10
> 3     6     0     3
> 4     6     1     4
> 5     8     0    14
> ```

Comment: Great pointer on the upcoming `across` functionality, very interesting! I guess I'll stick to `!!as.name(colname)` for now, as it seems the shortest, and without additional dependencies. But will be switching to `dplyr 1.0` when it's out. Either way, your answer is great going forward!

Comment: I actually often use `group_by_at()` when I write functions using dplyr, as it avoids the need for non-standard evaluation. `across` provides the same benefit, but is more flexible, so I've been switching over to it more recently.

Answer (score 5):

`!!` is not enough to unquote variable names for `dplyr`, you also need `rlang::sym`

```r
df %>% count( !!rlang::sym(colname)) 
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  city          n
  <fct>     <int>
1 Amsterdam     2
2 London        7
3 Paris         1
```

You can have a look at [a blog post](https://linogaliana.netlify.app/post/datatable/datatable-nse/) I wrote on the subject if you want more elements on SE vs NSE in `dplyr`