# dplyr mutate using dynamic column names

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame and want to create a new variable c = b/a:

```
# 1. Using actual variable names - it works:
x <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 2:6)
x %>% mutate(c = b/a)

# 2. Using dynamic variable names - doesn't work:
x <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 2:6)
var_a <- "a"
var_b <- "b"
var_c <- "c"
x %>% mutate_(var_c = var_b/var_a)
x %>% mutate(!!var_c := (!!var_b) / (!!var_a))
```

What is wrong? 
I looked at the answers here ([dplyr - mutate: use dynamic variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003574/dplyr-mutate-use-dynamic-variable-names)) - but am still unclear how it should be done.

Thank you!

Comment: `!!` is meant to be used with quosures or symbols, not strings. You can turn your strings into symbols with `as.name` or `rlang::sym()`.

Comment: Thank you! Wow, that's really long-ish.