# Dynamic variable names in rvest

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to set values with **rvest** for dynamic field names. So I retrieve the field name with the code below. `f.account` is a character of length one, containing a dynamic field name like *OCmaCMFgHij*

```
library(rvest)
url        <- "https://sv01.net-housting.de/user/index.php"
sp.session <- html_session(url)
f0         <- html_form(sp.session)
f.account  <- f0[[2]][['fields']][[1]]$name
```

Note: This is a little arbitrary example since f.account is not really dynamic in this case, but will always have the value `username`.

Now I want to set a fixed value to the field in the form with smth like this:

```
f1 <- set_values(f0, UQ(rlang::sym("f.account")) = "MyAccountName" ))
```

I tried to use the .dot statement or setNames as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003574/dplyr-mutate-use-dynamic-variable-names#43419232), but I have failed so far.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example.  What is `url`

Comment: thanks for the hint. I have ammended the question, so you see an example. `url` ist a web address.