# R mutate new columns based on previous ones and dynamically name them

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

This is not the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003574/dplyr-mutate-use-dynamic-variable-names) but an extension. What is the quickest way to generate multiple variables based on ones that you have created in `mutate` and dynamically name them. E.g.

```
library(dplyr)  
df<- data.frame(gg = rep(6:10),
                ba = rep(1:5))
df
  gg ba
1  6  1
2  7  2
3  8  3
4  9  4
5 10  5
```

desired output:

```
df_new
  gg ba diff.1 diff.2 sum_dif.1 sum_dif.2
1  6  1      5     10        25        50
2  7  2      5     10        25        50
3  8  3      5     10        25        50
4  9  4      5     10        25        50
5 10  5      5     10        25        50
```

Following the similar question I referenced I can get `diff.1` `diff.2`

```
myfun <- function(df, n) {
  varname <- paste("diff", n , sep=".")
  mutate(df, !!varname := (gg - ba)*n)
}

for(i in 1:2) {
  df <- myfun(df, n=i)
}
```

which gives

```
df
  gg ba diff.1 diff.2
1  6  1      5     10
2  7  2      5     10
3  8  3      5     10
4  9  4      5     10
5 10  5      5     10
```

But not sure how to pass the generated variable to another line within mutate, I thought something like this:

```
myfun <- function(df, n) {
  varname <- paste("diff", n , sep=".")
  varname2 <- paste("sum_dif", n , sep=".")
  mutate(df, !!varname := (gg - ba)*n,
             !!varname2 := sum(!!varname))
}
```

Also happy to get any other solutions, maybe `data.table`? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to convert the string to symbol before doing the evaluation (`!!`)

```
myfun <- function(df, n) {
 varname <- paste("diff", n , sep=".")
 varname2 <- paste("sum_dif", n , sep=".")
 mutate(df, !!varname := (gg - ba)*n,
         !!varname2 := sum(!! rlang::sym(varname)))
}
```

Now, we apply the `myfun`

```
for(i in 1:2) {
  df <- myfun(df, n=i)
 }

 df %>%
    select(gg, ba, matches('^diff'), matches('^sum'))
#   gg ba diff.1 diff.2 sum_dif.1 sum_dif.2
#1  6  1      5     10        25        50
#2  7  2      5     10        25        50
#3  8  3      5     10        25        50
#4  9  4      5     10        25        50
#5 10  5      5     10        25        50
```

Comment: Thanks. If you passed a named vector into the `for loop` instead, why doesn't the name of columns change accordingly? For the 1:2 example above, say they are named `mod1`, `mod2`, why aren't the columns then called `diff.mod1`, `diff.mod2` etc? I thought `varname <- paste("diff", name(n) , sep=".")` would work.

Comment: @user63230  Reason is due to the expression `(gg - ba)*n`  Here `n` is a number.  So, when you do the `for` loop, it needs to have some adjustment. i.e. `v1 <- c(mod1 = 1, mod2 = 2)` as named vector `for(nm in names(v1)) df <- myfun(df, n = v1[nm])`  works with the same names, but if we want to reflect the name changes, then change the `myfun` to reflect it i.e. `

Comment: @user63230 `myfun <- function(df, vec, n) { varname <- paste("diff", names(vec)[n], sep="."); varname2 <- paste("sum_diff", names(vec)[n], sep="."); mutate(df, !!varname := (gg = ba)*n, !!varname2 := sum(!! rlang::sym(varname)))};
 for(i in v1) df <- myfun(df, v1, n = i)`

Comment: Thank you but this is driving me mad. It works if we have say `v1 <- seq(-.8, -.7, .1)` and `names(v1) <- paste("mod", seq(-.8,-.7, .1), sep="")` but if we change the seq to this `v1 <- seq(-.8, -.7, .01)` and `names(v1) <- paste("mod", seq(-.8,-.7, .01), sep="") it wont work`Error: The LHS of := must be a string or a symbol`. Its just a finer seq, I dont understand why it does work? Any ideas?

Comment: @user63230  The reason is because we are indexing 1`names(vec)[n]` which takes integer index from 1 to any number..  You can loop through the sequence of 'v1' i.e. `for(i in seq_along(v1))` and then index the index

Comment: Sorry l don't get "index the index"?

Comment: @user63230  What i meant is that you need `v1[i]` inside the function for `n` and the names `names(v1[i])`