# Create Multiple Variables with Missing Date Values and Format in R

Tags: r, date, for-loop, paste, missing-data

I need to create variables with date as values from combining 3 fields or variables - a field pertaining to a `"month_i"`, another separate field pertaining to a `"day_i"` and a field with a value `"year_i"` with `i` from 0 to 9. But some of the `"day_i"` value is missing. I wanted to use the beginning day or the end day of the month for such. For example,

`StartingDate_0 <- paste(month_0, day_0, year_0)`

And I need to do that 10 times for the `"StartingDates_i"` (i = 0 to 9) and another 10 times for `"EndingDates_i"` (i = 0 to 9).

A portion of my code looks like this:

```
DataDates <- df3[("id")] %>% left_join(df3 %>% mutate(
  StartDate_0=paste(X.0.Bmonth,X.0.Bday,X.0.Byear, sep="-"),     
  StartDate_1=paste(X.1.Bmonth,X.1. Bday,X.1.Byear, sep="-"),
  StartDate_2=paste(X.2.Bmonth,X.2. Bday,X.2.Byear, sep="-"),
  StartDate_3=paste(X.3.Bmonth,X.3. Bday,X.3.Byear, sep="-"),
  StartDate_4=paste(X.4.Bmonth,X.4. Bday,X.4.Byear, sep="-"),
  StartDate_5=paste(X.5.Bmonth,X.5. Bday,X.5.Byear, sep="-"),
  StartDate_6=paste(X.6.Bmonth,X.6. Bday,X.6.Byear, sep="-"),
  StartDate_7=paste(X.7.Bmonth,X.7. Bday,X.7.Byear, sep="-"),
  StartDate_8=paste(X.8.Bmonth,X.8. Bday,X.8.Byear, sep="-"),
  StartDate_9=paste(X.9.Bmonth,X.9. Bday,X.9.Byear, sep="-"),
  EndDate_0=paste(X.0.Emonth,X.0.Eday,X.0.Eyear, sep="-"),     
  EndDate_1=paste(X.1.Emonth,X.1. Eday,X.1.Eyear, sep="-"),
  EndDate_2=paste(X.2.Emonth,X.2. Eday,X.2.Eyear, sep="-"),
  EndDate_3=paste(X.3.Emonth,X.3. Eday,X.3.Eyear, sep="-"),
  EndDate_4=paste(X.4.Emonth,X.4. Eday,X.4.Eyear, sep="-"),
  EndDate_5=paste(X.5.Emonth,X.5. Eday,X.5.Eyear, sep="-"),
  EndDate_6=paste(X.6.Emonth,X.6. Eday,X.6.Eyear, sep="-"),
  EndDate_7=paste(X.7.Emonth,X.7. Eday,X.7.Eyear, sep="-"),
  EndDate_8=paste(X.8.Emonth,X.8. Eday,X.8.Eyear, sep="-"),
  EndDate_9=paste(X.9.Emonth,X.9. Eday,X.9.Eyear, sep="-")))
```

And a sample result gave me for the `StartDate_0` of `"3-NA-2009"`. How can I go about doing it as `"3-1-2009"` but with `as.Date`? And for `Enddate_0` of `"5-NA-2011"` as `"5-31-2011`? I tried putting an `mdy()` before the paste and then use `lubridate` but it failed.

Forgive my scripting as I am really trying as a beginner R user.

Comment: Try `"StartingDate_0"=paste(month_0,ifelse(is.na(day_0),1,day_0),year_0)`

Comment: See [dplyr - mutate: use dynamic variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003574/dplyr-mutate-use-dynamic-variable-names) which will help you to reduce the copy-past.

Comment: @A.Suliman I will look into this linked document. I will also try the ifelse function you suggested. Thank you.

Comment: @A.Suliman, I hope you don't mind my asking if this line of codes will work?

Comment: DatesN <- function(df, n){
"  varname1 <- paste0(""StartDate_"", n),
  varname2 <-paste0(""EndDate_"",n)"
  df %>%
    mutate(!!varname1 := paste(X.n.Bmonth,
                              ifelse(is.na(X.n.Bday),1,X.n.Bday),
                              X.n.Byear,
                              sep="-")),
    mutate(!!varname2 := paste(X.n.Emonth,
                              ifelse(is.na(X.n.Eday),30,X.n.Eday),
                              X.n.Eyear,
                              sep="-")),
}

for(i in 0:3) {
  df3 <- DatesN(df=df3, n=i)
}