# How do I write a function that uses dplyr to check that a variable has no NA values?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have simple code that creates arbitrary example data:

```
library(assertr)
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
df <- tibble(id = 1:10, value = rnorm(10, 0, 1)) %>%
  mutate(value = if_else(abs(value) < 0.5, NA_real_, value))
```

The data looks like this:

```
> df
# A tibble: 10 x 2
      id   value
   <int>   <dbl>
 1     1  -0.626
 2     2  NA    
 3     3  -0.836
 4     4   1.60 
 5     5  NA    
 6     6  -0.820
 7     7  NA    
 8     8   0.738
 9     9   0.576
10    10  NA
```

Now, I'm trying to write a function that checks if any rows in a given column (in this case, the `value` column) have NA values and throws an error if they do. If they don't, it should return the original data, unmodified, so that the pipe can continue. This is simple without a function:

```
df %>% verify(sum(is.na(value)) == 0)

# Outputs "Error: assertr stopped execution"
```

Wrapping this in a function causes difficulty, however. I tried using `lazyeval`:

```
verify_not_missing <- function(.data, v) {
  .data %>% verify(sum(is.na(lazyeval::lazy(v))) == 0)
}
df %>% verify_not_missing(value)
```

But this doesn't throw any error or stop execution. It silently continues execution. Similarly, from the [dplyr programming vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html), I thought the following would work:

```
verify_not_missing <- function(.data, v) {
  .data %>% verify(sum(is.na(!! quo(v))) == 0)
}
df %>% verify_not_missing(value)
```

but that throws an error:

```
Error in is_quosure(e2) : argument "e2" is missing, with no default
```

I searched through some of the documentation and SO, including [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26003574/2766558), but some of the answers mention deprecated parts of `dplyr` that aren't much help (case in point, calling `vignette("nse")` reveals that the vignette no longer exists).

What am I missing here?

---

<sub>I'm using R v3.5.1, dplyr v0.7.7, and assertr v2.5 on an x64 Linux system</sub>

Comment: I think you might need `enquo` instead of `quo`

Comment: @MikeH. I still get the same error if I switch out `quo` for `enquo`

Comment: I've tried a million things but can't solve it yet. But first, you can simplify the non-function to ```df %>% verify(is.na(value))``` right?

Comment: It looks like `assertr` doesn't play very nicely with `dplyr`. You might need to do a non-standard evaluation without using dplyr's nice syntax

Comment: [Note that the development version of assertr implements ```rlang::eval_tidy``` internally, which may affect an answer for this.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not have to use `assertr` package, I think this solution can be considered.

```
library(tidyverse)

verify_not_missing <- function(.data) {
  col_na <- colSums(is.na(.data)) > 0 # larger than zero, than na value in that column
  if (any(col_na)) stop(gettextf("column %s is missing", 
                                 str_c(names(col_na)[col_na], collapse = ", ")))
}
```

By using `colSums(is.na(.))`, you can detect columns with `NA` values. If there is such column, it might be easy to print error message with its column names.

Also, I collapse `names()` for the multiple column case.

Applying to your dataset, we can get the result:

```
df %>% 
  verify_not_missing()
#> Error in verify_not_missing(.): column value is missing
```

Similarly, for additional column with `NA` values,

```
(mydf2 <- tibble(id = 1:10, value = rnorm(10, 0, 1)) %>%
  mutate(value1 = if_else(abs(value) < 0.5, NA_real_, value),
         value2 = if_else(abs(value) < 0.5, NA_real_, value)))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>       id   value  value1  value2
#>    <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1     1  1.51     1.51    1.51 
#>  2     2  0.390   NA      NA    
#>  3     3 -0.621   -0.621  -0.621
#>  4     4 -2.21    -2.21   -2.21 
#>  5     5  1.12     1.12    1.12 
#>  6     6 -0.0449  NA      NA    
#>  7     7 -0.0162  NA      NA    
#>  8     8  0.944    0.944   0.944
#>  9     9  0.821    0.821   0.821
#> 10    10  0.594    0.594   0.594

mydf2 %>% 
  verify_not_missing()
#> Error in verify_not_missing(.): column value1, value2 is missing
```

It prints `value1, value2` which include `NA`.

---

### Edit - Adding column argument

You can just `enquo(v)` and then use `%>% select(!!v)`. Then it returns columns for `v`. The remaining parts are the same.

```
verify_not_missing2 <- function(.data, v) {
  v <- enquo(v)
  col_na <-
    .data %>% 
    select(!!v) %>% # this returns v columns
    is.na() %>%
    colSums()
  col_na <- col_na > 0
  if (any(col_na)) stop(gettextf("column %s is missing", 
                                 str_c(names(col_na)[col_na], collapse = ", ")))
}
```

Applying this to the example,

```
df %>% 
  verify_not_missing2(value)
#> Error in verify_not_missing2(., value): column value is missing
```

Specifying `value` as argument, you can get error. For the multiple `NA` columns, in addition,

```
mydf2 %>% 
  verify_not_missing2(value)
#---------------------------
mydf2 %>% 
  verify_not_missing2(value1)
#> Error in verify_not_missing2(., value1): column value1 is missing
```

When you input column which is neither `value1` nor `value2`, then nothing will printed. On the other hand, you will get error with `value1` specified.

Also, you can specify multiple columns with `c()`.

```
mydf2 %>% 
  verify_not_missing2(v = c("value1", "value2"))
#> Error in verify_not_missing2(., v = c("value1", "value2")): column value1, value2 is missing
#----------------------------
mydf2 %>% 
  verify_not_missing2(v = c(value1, value2))
#> Error in verify_not_missing2(., v = c(value1, value2)): column value1, value2 is missing
```

---

### Edit2 - Returing original Data

```
verify_not_missing3 <- function(.data, v) {
  v <- enquo(v)
  col_na <-
    .data %>% 
    select(!!v) %>% 
    is.na() %>% 
    colSums()
  col_na <- col_na > 0
  if (any(col_na)) {
    stop(gettextf("column %s is missing", 
                                 str_c(names(col_na)[col_na], collapse = ", ")))
  } else {
    .data
  }
}
```

Additional `else { .data }` statement can return in non-error case.

If you gives `value`,

```
mydf2 %>% 
  verify_not_missing3(value)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>       id   value  value1  value2
#>    <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1     1  1.51     1.51    1.51 
#>  2     2  0.390   NA      NA    
#>  3     3 -0.621   -0.621  -0.621
#>  4     4 -2.21    -2.21   -2.21 
#>  5     5  1.12     1.12    1.12 
#>  6     6 -0.0449  NA      NA    
#>  7     7 -0.0162  NA      NA    
#>  8     8  0.944    0.944   0.944
#>  9     9  0.821    0.821   0.821
#> 10    10  0.594    0.594   0.594
```

On the other hand,

```
mydf2 %>% 
  verify_not_missing3(value1)
#> Error in verify_not_missing3(., value1): column value1 is missing
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't need (and in fact, don't want) the code to err out if *any* column in the tibble has `NA` values; only if certain columns do, hence why my original attempt at a function accepted a column name as an argument.

Comment: @MichaelA I added that option to handle that case.

Comment: These break the pipe though, right? Since they don't return the original data if no errors were found?

Comment: I did't know that you want to return the original data. Sorry for that. I think I keep mistaking. Since it has `if()` statement, I think it is easy to add that feature. I'll edit.

Comment: @MichaelA I add `if () {} else {.data}`.

Answer (score 1):

There are three possible ways to achieve this:

**First approach**

Using `eval()` with `substitute()`, like this:

```
verify_not_missing <- function(.data, v) {
  v <- eval(substitute(v), .data)
  .data %>% 
    verify(sum(is.na(v)) == 0)
}
```

---

**Second approach**

Using `rlang::eval_tidy()` with `enquo()`, like this:

```
verify_not_missing <- function(.data, v) {
  v <- rlang::eval_tidy(enquo(v), .data)
  .data %>% 
    verify(sum(is.na(v)) == 0)
}
```

---

**Third approach**

Using `!!enquo()` inside `select()` (you would need `colnames(.data)` to get the other columns)

```
verify_not_missing <- function(.data, v) {
  .data %>% 
    select(colnames(.data), v = !!enquo(v)) %>%
    verify(sum(is.na(v)) == 0)
}

df %>% verify_not_missing(value)
```

---

All of them produce the same result, which, using your data, looks like the following:

```
#verification [sum(is.na(v)) == 0] failed! (1 failure)

#    verb  redux_fn           predicate  column  index  value
#1 verify        NA  sum(is.na(v)) == 0      NA      1     NA

#Error: assertr stopped execution
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This seems to work, but is there a way to do this that won't break the pipe if `verify_not_missing` doesn't find missing values? Adding `return(.data)` to the function works, but I figured I'd ask in case there's a better way.

Comment: Try adding `%>% mutate(new_var = 2)` after calling `df %>% verify_not_missing(value)`. Your code drops the `id` variable and all other variables in the data frame except `value`, which means that trying to use your version of `verify_not_missing` in a pipe doesn't work. It breaks the pipe because it changes the data irreversibly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could do something similar in base R:

```
verify_not_missing <- function(.data, v) {
  !any(
    is.na(
      .data[[deparse(substitute(v))]]
    )
  )
} 

verify_not_missing(df, value)
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
missingna_df <- function (x) {
  x %>% 
    map_dbl(~sum(is.na(.))) %>% 
    as.data.frame()
}
```

This will show the missing values for all variables in a given data frame.