# How to get dplyr::mutate() to work with variable names when called inside a function?

Tags: r, dplyr, non-standard-evaluation

I am exploring data from the Pokemon API (not actually using the API, just pulling the .csv files from the github). In a file that contains the types of every Pokemon in narrow format (a Pokemon can have up to two types) called `pokemon_types.csv`, the types are encoded as integers (essentially factors). I want to label these levels by using a lookup table (`types.csv`), also from the API, that contains the levels as an `id` (1, 2, 3, etc.) and a corresponding `identifier` (normal, fighting, flying, etc.) which I want to use as the label.

```
> head(read_csv(path("pokemon_types.csv")), 10)
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   pokemon_id type_id  slot
        <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1          1      12     1
 2          1       4     2
 3          2      12     1
 4          2       4     2
 5          3      12     1
 6          3       4     2
 7          4      10     1
 8          5      10     1
 9          6      10     1
10          6       3     2
> head(read_csv(path("types.csv")))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
     id identifier generation_id damage_class_id
  <dbl> <chr>              <dbl>           <dbl>
1     1 normal                 1               2
2     2 fighting               1               2
3     3 flying                 1               2
4     4 poison                 1               2
5     5 ground                 1               2
6     6 rock                   1               2
```

My code works when I pipe all of the steps individually, but since I am going to perform this labeling step at least a dozen times or so I tried to put it into a function. The problem is that when I call the function instead (which has exactly the same steps as far as I can tell) it throws an `object not found` error.

The Setup:

```
library(readr)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

options(readr.num_columns = 0)

# Append web directory to filename
path <- function(x) {
  paste0("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/",
         "PokeAPI/pokeapi/master/data/v2/csv/", x)
}
```

The offending function:

```
# Use lookup table to label factor variables
label <- function(data, variable, lookup) {
  mutate(data, variable = factor(variable, 
                                 levels = read_csv(path(lookup))$id,
                                 labels = read_csv(path(lookup))$identifier))
}
```

This version, which doesn't use the function, works:

```
df.types <-
  read_csv(path("pokemon_types.csv")) %>%
  mutate(type_id = factor(type_id, 
                          levels = read_csv(path("types.csv"))$id,
                          labels = read_csv(path("types.csv"))$identifier)) %>%
  spread(slot, type_id)

head(df.types)
```

it returns:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  pokemon_id `1`   `2`   
       <dbl> <fct> <fct> 
1          1 grass poison
2          2 grass poison
3          3 grass poison
4          4 fire  NA    
5          5 fire  NA    
6          6 fire  flying
```

This version, which uses the function, does not:

```
df.types <-
  read_csv(path("pokemon_types.csv")) %>%
  label(type_id, "types.csv") %>%
  spread(slot, type_id)
```

it returns:

```
Error in factor(variable, 
                levels = read_csv(path(lookup))$id, 
                labels = read_csv(path(lookup))$identifier) : 
  object 'type_id' not found
```

I know that there are several things that may be sub-optimal here (downloading `lookup` twice each time for instance) but I am more interested in why a function that seems identical to some written code makes it not work anymore. I am sure I am just making a silly mistake.

Comment: This is yet another duplicate asking about dplyr's [Non-Standard Evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/non-standard-evaluation) of function arguments. This has nothing to do with `factor()`. The only reason you see `factor()` getting confused is because it's inside a `dplyr::mutate()` call.

Comment: Be sure to read the programming with dplyr guide: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dplyr - mutate: use dynamic variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003574/dplyr-mutate-use-dynamic-variable-names)

Comment: @MrFlick I didn't even know about non-standard evaluation, thank you and sorry for the duplicate. This seems more complicated than I thought, is it standard to figure out how to manage NSE to use dplyr inside functions, or is it more common to avoid using dplyr in functions entirely?

Comment: It's really a personal preference. But it's probably better to get acquainted with `!!` and quosures sooner rather than later because at some point you're going to need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the helpful comments I was able to learn all about non-standard evaluation and figure out a solution:

```
label <- function(data, variable, lookup) {
  variable <- enquo(variable)
  data %>%
    mutate(!!variable := factor(!!variable, 
                                 levels = read_csv(path(lookup))$id,
                                 labels = read_csv(path(lookup))$identifier))
}
```

The key features are `enquo()`, which acts as a "quasiquote", `!!`, which "unquotes" the variable so it can be interpreted through the argument, and `:=`, which allows for unquoting on the both sides.

I tried and failed to implement a solution that avoided `dplyr` entirely, but at least this works.