# Are there languages besides R that allow non-standard evaluation?

Tags: r, nse, non-standard-evaluation

I'm curious if non-standard evaluation is used in languages besides R. If so, how is it implemented elsewhere?

[Non-standard evaluation defined in *Advanced R* by Hadley Wickham](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56624460/would-it-be-possible-in-javascript-or-python-to-implement-something-like-non-st) has some examples of non-standard evaluation in R, where columns are referred to without using quotes in the arguments:

```
# df has columns "A" and "B"
df = mutate(df, C=A*B)
lm(data=df, A~B)
```

Comment: Most LISP-based languages can do things like that.  R was originally based on a Scheme interpreter.

Comment: The Wikipedia article for metaprogramming is very helpful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming

Comment: See also [What languages give you access to the AST to modify during compilation?](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/2134/what-languages-give-you-access-to-the-ast-to-modify-during-compilation) on Programming Language Design.

Comment: Wouldn't `transform()`, a base function, be a better example than `mutate()`, from an add-on package?

Comment: Since OP is reading Wickham's book they may be less aware of the base-R alternatives to tidyverse/rlang stuff ...  (someone should put together an answer based on the comments ...)

Comment: @AkselA I just copied the code examples from the linked post. I don't think it matters for the question whether the example is base R or not

Comment: I think your question has been mostly answered: most lisp-like languages support it, there are many others. Other than that, is there a concrete question? Are you looking for a list of languages outside of what has been provided so far in comments? I suggest either provide some clarity on what exactly you need, or perhaps this question is not focused enough or lacks clarity/detail for the "concrete question" that StackOverflow tends to prefer. (I'm not saying it's not an _interesting_ topic.)