# dplyr - mutate: columns escaped are false in DT:datatable title edited; was (dplyr - mutate: use dynamic variable names...(used for `DT::datatable`))

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr, dt

This tips [dplyr - mutate: use dynamic variable names, answer of @Tom Roth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49311813/10489562) works very well, but I have a little issue.

[edit: It seems than dynamic variables are not the cause. Reprex added  /edit]

If I change  an initial column `myCol` to an url (for example), and copy the old column `myColInitialValue` at the end of the dataframe `df` with a new name, therefore I thought that a `which(colnames(df)=='myCol')` send back the col # of `myColInitialValue` but It seems to be an issue in DT::datatable()

My goal is for the `escape` parameter of `DT::datatable()`. I use `escape=FALSE` in waiting that. With constants it doesn't work also but the [DT package](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/blob/master/R/datatables.R) seems also get the bad # column. :)

Here is my source with the issue of the bad column escaped:

- the # column is correct
- when I was debugging I get a dataframe with incorrect order of column 
  but I didn't get again, I didn't reproduce it.
- but even with the correct number with `which()` the escaped column displayed in shiny/ datatable is wrong

```
output$Myoutputdatatable <- DT::renderDataTable( { 
  mydatatable<-Myreactivefunction()
  mydatatable<- ( mydatatable 
                  %>% ungroup() 
                  %>% get_url_pdf(.,nom_colonne_initiale_pour_url = "s_code", 
                                  nom_colonne_code_rempl="s_code_old", 
                                  repertoire_cible = my_path_of_pdf, nom_colonne_test_fichier="s_exists")

                  %>% get_url_pdf(.,nom_colonne_initiale_pour_url = "sp_code", 
                                  nom_colonne_code_rempl="sp_code_old", 
                                  repertoire_cible = my_path_of_pdf, nom_colonne_test_fichier="sp_exists")

  ) 
  escape_vector<-which(colnames(mydatatable) %in% list("s_code","sp_code"))  

  res<-DT::datatable(  mydatatable,
                       style = "bootstrap",   class = "compact", filter='top', 
                       selection = c("single"),
                       escape=escape_vector,
                       options = list(
                         deferRender = TRUE,
                         bSortClasses = TRUE,iDisplayLength = 20,   width = "100%",
                         scrollX=TRUE ,
                         lengthMenu  = list(c(5, 25, 50, 75, 100, -1), list('5', '25','50','75','100', 'All')),                      
                         search = list(
                           smart = TRUE,
                           regex = TRUE, 
                           caseInsensitive = TRUE
                         )                      

                       )
  );

  res <- ( res 
           %>% formatStyle( columns = c("s_code_old"), 
                            valueColumns = c("s_code_old"), target='row', 
                            color = styleEqual(c('__UNKNOWN__'), c("red")) 
           )
  )
  res
} )
```

With my function with the use of the answer of @Tom Roth about dynamic variable in `mutate()`.

```
get_url_pdf <-function (mydatatable,nom_colonne_initiale_pour_url, nom_colonne_code_rempl, 
                        repertoire_cible,nom_colonne_test_fichier = "" ) {

  # exemple mutate(iris [1:3,], !!("varcible") :=  UQ(rlang::sym("Species") ))


  (mydatatable
   %>% ungroup()
   %>% mutate (
     nom_colonne_test_fichier=nom_colonne_test_fichier,
     varsource =  !!(rlang::sym(nom_colonne_initiale_pour_url) ),
     nom_fichier_pdf=paste0(gsub("\\.", "_",  varsource),'.pdf'),
     var_nom_colonne_test_fichier=ifelse(nom_colonne_test_fichier=='',"",UQ(rlang::sym(nom_colonne_test_fichier))),
     fichier_pdf_existe=ifelse(var_nom_colonne_test_fichier=="",file_test("-f", paste0(repertoire_cible , nom_fichier_pdf)),var_nom_colonne_test_fichier),     
     varcible =  ifelse(fichier_pdf_existe,paste0('<a class="url_pdf" href="http://',hostipserver ,hostportserver,'/rapportpdfpath/',nom_fichier_pdf,'"  target = "_blank">',varsource,'</a>'), varsource)  ,    
     !!(nom_colonne_initiale_pour_url) :=varcible  , 
     !!(nom_colonne_code_rempl) :=varsource         
   )
  )

}
```

**EDIT: REPREX ADDED**

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

hostipserver <- str_trim(system("hostname -I", intern=TRUE))
hostportserver <- ":8080"



app<-
  shinyApp(
    ui = basicPage(
      navbarMenu("Bla",
                 tabPanel("blabla",
                          fluidPage(
                            h3("outblabla_1"),
                            p("toto_1 and toto_2 have to be worked urls but only toto_2 is ok. varcible is a worked url but I don't want it."),
                            fluidRow(
                              column (12,
                                      div(DT::dataTableOutput('outblabla_1'), 
                                          style = "font-size:80%;white-space: nowrap;width:93%")
                              )
                            ),
                            h3("outblabla_2"),
                             p("toto_1 and toto_2 have to be worked urls but only toto_2 is ok"),
                            fluidRow(
                              column (12,
                                      div(DT::dataTableOutput('outblabla_2'), 
                                          style = "font-size:80%;white-space: nowrap;width:93%")
                              )
                            )                            
                          )
                 )
      )           
    ),

    server = function(input, output) {

      blabla <-  reactive({
        test<-data.frame(        
          matrix (rep(c(c(999.2,2), 1200), 4000), nrow = 40, ncol = 30)
        )
        colnames(test) <-  paste0("toto_", 1:30)

        test<-test %>% mutate (toto_9 = ifelse (toto_9==2,TRUE,FALSE))

        return( test)        

      })
      get_url_pdf <-function (mydatatable,nom_colonne_initiale_pour_url, nom_colonne_code_rempl, 
                              repertoire_cible,nom_colonne_test_fichier = "" ) {

        # exemple mutate(iris [1:3,], !!("varcible") :=  UQ(rlang::sym("Species") ))


        (mydatatable
         %>% ungroup()
         %>% mutate (
           nom_colonne_test_fichier=nom_colonne_test_fichier,
           varsource =  !!(rlang::sym(nom_colonne_initiale_pour_url) ),
           nom_fichier_pdf=paste0(gsub("\\.", "_",  varsource),'.pdf'),
           var_nom_colonne_test_fichier=ifelse(nom_colonne_test_fichier=='',"",UQ(rlang::sym(nom_colonne_test_fichier))),
           fichier_pdf_existe=ifelse(var_nom_colonne_test_fichier=="",file_test("-f", paste0(repertoire_cible , nom_fichier_pdf)),var_nom_colonne_test_fichier),     
           varcible =  ifelse(fichier_pdf_existe,paste0('<a class="url_pdf" href="http://',hostipserver ,hostportserver,'/rapportpdfpath/',nom_fichier_pdf,'"  target = "_blank">',varsource,'</a>'), varsource)  ,    
           !!(nom_colonne_initiale_pour_url) :=varcible  , 
           !!(nom_colonne_code_rempl) :=varsource         
         )
        )

      }      

      output$outblabla_1<- DT::renderDataTable( { 
        mydatatable<-blabla()
        mydatatable<- ( mydatatable
                        %>% ungroup()
                        %>% get_url_pdf(.,nom_colonne_initiale_pour_url = "toto_1",
                                        nom_colonne_code_rempl="toto_1_old",
                                        repertoire_cible = my_path_of_pdf, nom_colonne_test_fichier="toto_9"
                        )
                        %>% get_url_pdf(.,nom_colonne_initiale_pour_url = "toto_2",
                                        nom_colonne_code_rempl="toto_2_old",
                                        repertoire_cible = my_path_of_pdf, nom_colonne_test_fichier="toto_9"
                        )                        
        )




        escape_vector<-which(colnames(mydatatable) %in% list("toto_1","toto_2"))  
        print('escape 1' , paste0(escape_vector,(dput(escape_vector))))
        res<-DT::datatable(  mydatatable,
                             style = "bootstrap",   class = "compact", filter='top', 
                             selection = c("single"),
                             escape=escape_vector,
                             options = list(
                               deferRender = TRUE,
                               bSortClasses = TRUE,iDisplayLength = 5,   width = "100%",
                               scrollX=TRUE ,
                               lengthMenu  = list(c(5, 25, 50, 75, 100, -1), list('5', '25','50','75','100', 'All')),                      
                               search = list(
                                 smart = TRUE,
                                 regex = TRUE, 
                                 caseInsensitive = TRUE
                               )                      

                             )
        );
      })

      output$outblabla_2<- DT::renderDataTable( { 
        mydatatable<-blabla()
        mydatatable<- ( mydatatable
                        %>% ungroup()
                        %>% mutate(
                          nom_fichier_pdf_1='a',#paste0(gsub("\\.", "_",  toto_1),'.pdf'),
                          nom_fichier_pdf_2='b',#paste0(gsub("\\.", "_",  toto_2),'.pdf'),

                        toto_1_old=toto_1,
                        toto_1=ifelse(toto_9,paste0('<a class="url_pdf" href="http://',hostipserver ,hostportserver,'/rapportpdfpath/',nom_fichier_pdf_1,'"  target = "_blank">',toto_1,'</a>'), toto_1),
                        toto_2_old=toto_2,
                        toto_2=ifelse(toto_9,paste0('<a class="url_pdf" href="http://',hostipserver ,hostportserver,'/rapportpdfpath/',nom_fichier_pdf_2,'"  target = "_blank">',toto_2,'</a>'), toto_2)                        
                        )


        )




        escape_vector<-which(colnames(mydatatable) %in% list("toto_1","toto_2"))  
        print('escape 2' , paste0(escape_vector,(dput(escape_vector))))
        res<-DT::datatable(  mydatatable,
                             style = "bootstrap",   class = "compact", filter='top', 
                             selection = c("single"),
                             escape=c(1,2),
                             options = list(
                               deferRender = TRUE,
                               bSortClasses = TRUE,iDisplayLength = 5,   width = "100%",
                               scrollX=TRUE ,
                               lengthMenu  = list(c(5, 25, 50, 75, 100, -1), list('5', '25','50','75','100', 'All')),                      
                               search = list(
                                 smart = TRUE,
                                 regex = TRUE, 
                                 caseInsensitive = TRUE
                               )                      

                             )
        );
      })      
    })
shiny::runApp(app)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the answer in [rstudio/DT#691](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/691), since the rowname is regarded as one column, you should add an additional 1L on the column position. Moreover, since the real intent is to *unescape* the certain columns, there should be a minus sign on the vector provided.

In short,

```r
escape_vector <- which(colnames(mydatatable) %in% list("toto_1","toto_2"))
```

should be changed to

```r
escape_vector <- -( which(colnames(mydatatable) %in% c("toto_1","toto_2")) + 1L )
```