# r - How to Create loop for plotting in dabestr?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, plot

I am using dabestr for plotting estimation plots, for a single variable I succeed, but I want to create a batch of plots with the for loop and it not work.

```
library(dabestr)
plot(dabest(iris, Species,  Petal.Width, idx = c("setosa", "versicolor"), paired = FALSE))
```

I want to plot Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width in a for loop.
Would anyone help? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not with the for statement, it's with the `dabest` function. It's made to **only** accept column names as given in `.data` so a string with the column name doesn't work...

After digging a bit, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49311813/6478701) very helpful for `dplyr` related problems with variable names.

```
library(dabestr)
library(ggpubr) # for ggarrange

to_plot <- c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width")
plots <- lapply(to_plot, function(co){
  plot(dabest(iris, Species, UQ(rlang::sym(co)), idx = c("setosa", "versicolor"), paired = FALSE))
})

ggarrange(plotlist = plots, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
```

Note that `UQ(rlang::sym(my_string))` is doing the magic here. This yields the following plot.

[image]

Comment: dplyr-related functions can behave unpredictably with automated actions / fors /lapplys, etc. don't hesitate to look around for similar problems if you have other issues in the future.