# How to make new dataframe columns from factor levels (& troubleshoot mutate error)

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, dplyr, levels

My searches on SO & elsewhere are coming up with interesting solutions to problems that have similar search terms but not my issue.  Thought I found a solution, but the error is leaving me quite puzzled.  I'm trying to learn tidyverse approaches better, but I appreciate any solution strategies.

**Aim:** Create new vector columns in a dataframe where each new vector is named from the factor level of an existing dataframe vector.
*The code solution should be dynamic so that it can be applied to factors with any number of levels.*

**Test data**

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1:5), y=letters[1:5])
```

Which produces as expected

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x: int  1 2 3 4 5
 $ y: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5
> df
  x y
1 1 a
2 2 b
3 3 c
4 4 d
5 5 e
```

and when finished should look like

```
> df
  x y  a  b  c  d  e
1 1 a NA NA NA NA NA
2 2 b NA NA NA NA NA
3 3 c NA NA NA NA NA
4 4 d NA NA NA NA NA
5 5 e NA NA NA NA NA
```

**Tidy for loop approach**

```
library(tidyverse)

for (i in 1:length(levels(df$y))) {
  df <- mutate(df, levels(df$y)[i] = NA)
}
```

but that gives me the following error:

```
> for (i in 1:length(levels(df$y))) {
+   df <- mutate(df, levels(df$y)[i] = NA)
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"for (i in 1:length(levels(df$y))) {
  df <- mutate(df, levels(df$y)[i] ="
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

Troubleshooting, I removed the loop and simplified the mutate to see if it works in general, which it will with or without the quotation marks *(note, I reran the test data to start fresh)*.

```
levels(df$y)[1]
> "a"

df <- mutate(df, a = NA)
df <- mutate(df, "a" = NA) # works the same as the previous line
> df
  x y  a
1 1 a NA
2 2 b NA
3 3 c NA
4 4 d NA
5 5 e NA
```

Substituting the levels function back in, but without the loop returns the mutate error *(note, I reran the test data to start fresh)*:

```
> df <- mutate(df, levels(df$y)[1] = NA)
Error: unexpected '=' in "df <- mutate(df, levels(df$y)[1] ="
```

I continue to get the same error is I try to use .data=df to specify the dataset or wrap as.character(), paste(), or paste0() around the levels function--which I picked up other various solutions online.  Nor is R just being picky if I restructure the code using the %>% pipe.

What about the equal sign is unexpected with my levels code substitution (and potential newb mistakes)?
Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure why not just something like `df[, levels(df$y)] <- NA`?

Comment: The argument name you pass to a function isn't evaluated. That is, something like `foo = "na.rm"; mean(c(1, NA), foo = TRUE))` doesn't work. That's more-or-less why your attempt with `levels(df$y)[i] = NA` fails.  Have a read of the [Programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) vignette to learn about workarounds. Or, for the newest approach, try using `{{` and `:=` from `rlang` [as shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59224230/903061).

Comment: Thanks @arg0naut91!  Your solution is short, elegant, and works!  So simplistic in the approach, it totally eluded me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting solutions for others based on comments received, and so I can mark this question as solved.  ***Please give up votes to @arg0naut91 and @Gregor for their solutions & guided help.***

Test data

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1:5), y=letters[1:5])
```

**Solution 1: base R**

@arg0naut91 provided an elegant base R solution:

```
df[, levels(df$y)] <- NA
df
  x y  a  b  c  d  e
1 1 a NA NA NA NA NA
2 2 b NA NA NA NA NA
3 3 c NA NA NA NA NA
4 4 d NA NA NA NA NA
5 5 e NA NA NA NA NA
```

**Solution 2: using quo() and :=**

@Gregor's guidance & useful links showed how some functions, and pretty much all of the tidyverse, does not evaluate objects as we might expect.

*First test with a single new column:*

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1:5), y=letters[1:5]) # refresh test data

varlevel <- levels(df$y)[1] # where level 1=a
df <- mutate(df, !!varlevel := NA)
rm(varlevel) # cleanup
df
  x y  a
1 1 a NA
2 2 b NA
3 3 c NA
4 4 d NA
5 5 e NA
```

*Then put it into the for loop to capture each factor level as a new column:*

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1:5), y=letters[1:5]) # refresh test data

for (i in 1:length(levels(df$y))) {
+   varlevel <- levels(df$y)[i]
+   df <- mutate(df, !!varlevel := NA)
+   rm(varlevel) # cleanup
+   }
df
  x y  a  b  c  d  e
1 1 a NA NA NA NA NA
2 2 b NA NA NA NA NA
3 3 c NA NA NA NA NA
4 4 d NA NA NA NA NA
5 5 e NA NA NA NA NA
```