# Can not use dynamic variable names with dplyr in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I see the answers on this [website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003574/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-dplyr), but it can not solve my problem.

What I want is that use dynamic variable names both on LHS and RHS within `summarize`.

This is a simple example to show what I have tried:

why I use `paste0('carb')` not use `carb` directly is that on the position(`paste0('carb')`) is a dynamic variable like this `paste0('temp', n)` and `n` is a series of numbers in my real situation.

```
library(dplyr)
sumay1 <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(!!paste0('carb', 100) := mean(paste0('carb'), na.rm = T))

sumay2 <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(!!paste0('carb', 100) := mean(sym('carb'), na.rm = T))

sumay3 <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(!!paste0('carb', 100) := mean({{paste0('carb')}}, na.rm = T))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second case, we need to evaluate (`!!`) the `sym`bol

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
   group_by(cyl) %>% 
   summarise(!!paste0('carb', 100) := mean(!!sym('carb'), na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#    cyl carb100
#* <dbl>   <dbl>
#1     4    1.55
#2     6    3.43
#3     8    3.5
```

The `{{}}` is mainly used within a function where we pass unquoted arguments and it is equivalent to `enquo` + `!!`

Comment: Thanks, it really works. I don't understand why use `!!` and `variable names` on the LHS but use both `!!` and `sym()` with `variable names` on the RHL. Is that because of  `summarise()` and `mean()`?

Comment: @zhiweili We are using `:=` and the `!!` is to evaluate the variable names, In the RHS, the evaluation is to get the value of the column