# Loop character variable and interact it to create names in dplyr

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, character, names

I want to loop through the names of a character variable of this type:

```
names_list <- c("USA", "VEN", "CHE")
```

Then, I create the following loop:

```
for (i in names_list) {
  set.seed(123333)
  test <- predictors_no_NA %>%
    filter(ISO3_baci != i)

predictions <- predict(rf150, test, predict.all=TRUE, type = "prob")
  predictions <- as.data.frame(predictions[1])
  predictions <- predictions %>%
    select(aggregate.1) %>%
    rename(predictions[i] = aggregate.1)    % HERE APPEARS THE 1st PROBLEM

  test_RF_[i] <- cbind(test, predictions)   % HERE APPEARS THE 2nd PROBLEM
}
```

Note that variable "rf150" is created inside the loop without any problem (don't show the code here).

The problem arises when I want to add the string element of the loop (e.g. "USA") to my created name "predictions_[i]" or "test_RF_[i]", so that I can get a variable that is called: "predictions_USA" or "test_RF_USA" as well as "predictions_VEN" or "test_RF_VEN" and "predictions_CHE" or "test_RF_CHE"

Any clue?

Regards

Comment: Have you try with assign + pasteo ?? <https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assign.html>

Comment: I have tried it but either I don't implement I correctly or it really does not work inside a dplyr framework

Comment: I the second problem it should work, I think. In the first maybe using {{ }}

Comment: Your problem is that `deplyr`, along with other `tidyverse` packages, uses non-standard evaluation.  One solution is to use `{{`` and `}}` as suggested by @SantiagoI.Hurtado.  However, the structure I think you are trying to use is not [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).  I strongly suggest adapting your workflow to make it tidy.  A little effort now will save you much pain later on.

Comment: Thanks to both @SantiagoI.Hurtado and Limey. Helpful recommendations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, for the dynamic renaming in your loop, the following snippet should help (I've taken the freedom to alter it a little:

```
library(tibble) # if you want to use as_tibble() rather than as.data.frame()
library(dplyr)

predictions <- predict(rf150, test, predict.all=TRUE, type = "prob") %>%
    .[1] %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    select(!!paste0('predictions_',i) := aggregate.1)
```

There's a very helpful and detailed answer on the topic of dynamic variable names in `dplyr` [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003574/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-dplyr/26003971#26003971).

Alternative solution, since you had already selected only the one column that you wanted to colbind:

```
predictions  <- [...] %>%
    select(aggregate.1) %>%
    `colnames<-`(paste0('predictions_',i))
```

---

Secondly, to assign the data frame to a variable, as commented by Santiago above, `assign` should get you there:

```
assign(
    paste0('test_RF_',i),
    cbind(test, predictions),
    envir=globalenv()
)
```