# Mutate with dynamic variable names

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `DF` with two columns and I would like to offset my second column with `mutate`. The problem is that column names are variable and I don't know how to use `mutate` in this case.

I tried to follow the example of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003574/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-dplyr), but I couldn't reach my goal.

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:150, y = 1:150)

df %>%
    mutate(x = lag(x, 1))
```

My variable `x` changes its name with another `DF's`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another simple thing to do is to use `.data` to reference the data from the pipe. You can then select out the variable as usual with `[[`.

```r
df <- data.frame(x = 1:150, y = 1:150)

variable <- "x"

df %>%
  mutate(x = lag(.data[[variable]], 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Outside of a function, you might want to use the `sym` function with a `bang-bang` operator:

```
variable="Petal.Width"
df %>% mutate(x = lag(!!sym(variable), 1))
```

In a function, you can use the `curly-curly` (`{{...}}`) operator like this:

```
lag_df = function(df, variable){
  df %>% mutate(x = lag({{variable}}, 1))
}
iris %>% lag_df(Petal.Width) %>% select(x, Petal.Width)
```

`{{variable}}` is somehow similar to `!!enquo(variable)`.

You can learn more about this in the "Programming with dplyr
" [vignette](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).