# How to access an existing column in mutate() with a string variable

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr, rlang

I already read [Use dynamic variable names in `dplyr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003574/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-dplyr)
but my problem is to mutate an already existing column with a column name stored as a string variable.

```
data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~colA, ~colB,
  1, 2,
  3, 4
)

namestring <- "colA"

----

> data
# A tibble: 2 x 2
   colA  colB
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2
2     3     4

> namestring
[1] "colA"
```

Now I want to modify the `colA` using `namestring`

Wanted output without namestring is like this.

```
data %>%
  dplyr::mutate(colA = colB * 100)

## A tibble: 2 x 2
#   colA  colB
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1   200     2
#2   400     4
```

But it gives me error using dplyr programming

```
namestring <- "colA"
data %>%
  dplyr::mutate(.data[[namestring]] = colB + 2)

# Error: unexpected '=' in:
# "data %>%
#   dplyr::mutate(.data[[namestring]] ="
```

`filter` and `select` don't produce same kind of error using `.data[[string]]` on LHS

```
data %>%
  dplyr::filter(.data[[namestring]] == 3)

## A tibble: 1 x 2
#   colA  colB
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     3     4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `:=` with `!!`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
    mutate(!! namestring := colB * 100)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#   colA  colB
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1   200     2
#2   400     4
```

---

Or it can be within `across`

```
data %>%
    mutate(across(all_of(namestring), ~ colB* 100))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#   colA  colB
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1   200     2
#2   400     4
```

Comment: @alperceire I showed two options.  The first one is when there is a single column and you want to modify it.  Second with `across` is more general as it can take more than one or more columns