# r/dplyr: Using dynamically named variables in UDF

Tags: r, dplyr, user-defined-functions

I am somewhat new to writing user defined functions with `dplyr` and I would like to use dynamically defined variables within my function. I've gotten part of the way there with documentation [here](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html) and [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003574/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-dplyr) but I am afraid that I might not have the right nomenclature to find what I am trying to do.

I would like to define a function where it creates a variable in a `mutate` call and then uses that variable in other calls. For example,

```
library(tidyverse)
library(PropCIs)

for_share_plot <- function(data, dummy, group_var){

    dummy_sum <- paste0(quo_name(enquo(dummy)), "_sum")

    data %>% 
       mutate("{{dummy}}_sum" := sum({{dummy}})) %>% 
       mutate("{{dummy}}_prop" := (!!dummy_sum)/{{group_var}},
              "{{dummy}}_lowerci" := scoreci(!!dummy_sum, {{group_var}}, conf.level = 0.95)$conf.int[1],
              "{{dummy}}_upperci" := scoreci(!!dummy_sum, {{group_var}}, conf.level = 0.95)$conf.int[2])
}

df <- mtcars %>%
    add_count(cyl, name = 'group_n') %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>%
    for_share_plot(data = ., dummy = am, group_var = group_n)
```

returns the following error message

```
#Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `am_prop`.
#x non-numeric argument to binary operator
#ℹ Input `am_prop` is `"am_sum"/group_n`.
#ℹ The error occured in group 1: cyl = 4.
```

I understand that it is interpreting the first input to `{{dummy}}_prop` as a string but I don't know how else to reference the previously defined column from just above. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You correctly identified that `dummy_sum` is a string, so you can convert it to a symbol that `!!` can evaluate by using the `sym()` command.

Try the following modification to your code:

```
for_share_plot <- function(data, dummy, group_var){

    dummy_sum <- sym(paste0(quo_name(enquo(dummy)), "_sum"))

    data %>% 
       mutate("{{dummy}}_sum" := sum({{dummy}})) %>% 
       mutate("{{dummy}}_prop" := (!!dummy_sum)/{{group_var}},
              "{{dummy}}_lowerci" := scoreci(!!dummy_sum, {{group_var}}, conf.level = 0.95)$conf.int[1],
              "{{dummy}}_upperci" := scoreci(!!dummy_sum, {{group_var}}, conf.level = 0.95)$conf.int[2])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.data` pronoun to refer to column names.

```
library(dplyr)
library(PropCIs)

for_share_plot <- function(data, dummy, group_var){
  
  dummy_sum <- paste0(quo_name(enquo(dummy)), "_sum")
  
  data %>% 
    mutate("{{dummy}}_sum" := sum({{dummy}}),
           "{{dummy}}_prop" := .data[[dummy_sum]]/{{group_var}},
           "{{dummy}}_lowerci" := scoreci(.data[[dummy_sum]], {{group_var}}, conf.level = 0.95)$conf.int[1],
           "{{dummy}}_upperci" := scoreci(.data[[dummy_sum]], {{group_var}}, conf.level = 0.95)$conf.int[2])
}

mtcars %>%
  add_count(cyl, name = 'group_n') %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  for_share_plot(dummy = am, group_var = group_n)
```