# Loop over variables names in mutate and ifelse

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I have a tibble df and I'm trying to fill NAs using `lm` function. The filling must be done taking into account the variable t.

```
t = rep(c('a', 'b'), rep(4, 2))
v1 = c(1, 2, NA, 4, 5, NA, 7, 8)
v2 = runif(8)
v3 = rnorm(8)
v4 = rnorm(8)
v5 = c(NA, 5, 3, 1, NA, NA, 10, 0)

df = tibble(t, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5)
```

To do this quickly I tried using the `for` loop. As can be seen below:

```
vars = c('v1', 'v5')

for (n in vars){
  for (i in c('a', 'b')) {
    fit = lm(rlang::sym(n) ~ v3 + v2, df[df$t==i, ])
  df %>%
    mutate(pred = predict(fit,.))%>%
    mutate( rlang::sym(n) = ifelse(is.na(rlang::sym(n) )& t==i, pred, rlang::sym(n)  ))

}}
```

The main idea is replace n by v1 and v5. But this code doesn't work. Instead `rlang::sym(n)` I tried `get(n)`, `!!as.name(n)` as stated [Use dynamic variable names in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003574/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-dplyr?noredirect=1&lq=1)
. I'm using `dplyr` version 1.04.

How can I get `mutate()`, `ifelse` and `lm` to use dynamic name as variable name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap `expr()` around `(!!rlang::sym(n) ~ v3 + v2)`. Next you need to evaluate the LHS in your mutate call before your RHS. This is done with `!!` operator and `:=`. However, code is generating warnings.

```
t = rep(c('a', 'b'), rep(4, 2))
v1 = c(1, 2, NA, 4, 5, NA, 7, 8)
v2 = runif(8)
v3 = rnorm(8)
v4 = rnorm(8)
v5 = c(NA, 5, 3, 1, NA, NA, 10, 0)

df = tibble(t, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5)

vars = c('v1', 'v5')

for (n in vars){
  for (i in c('a', 'b')) {
    fit = lm(expr(!!rlang::sym(n) ~ v3 + v2), df[df$t==i, ])
    df %>%
      mutate(pred = predict(fit,.))%>%
      mutate( !!n := ifelse(is.na(n )& t==i, pred, n))
  }}
```