# What does the bang bang operator (!!) do?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am new to R language and I am trying to understand what the `!!` operator is doing here

```
df %>% if (stringr::str_length("column")>0) dplyr::filter(., !!rlang::parse_expr(expr)) else .}
```

Comment: It is bang-bang operation.  If you check the documentation,, help("!!")` gives more info

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and, in particular, provide complete reproducible code with all inputs and library statements.  also code should be indented 4 spaces in which case SO will format it for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use dynamic variable names in \`dplyr\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003574/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-dplyr)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43419232/10323798

Comment: See the official rlang documentation: https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/topic-inject.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a bang-bang operator used to force early evaluation of part of an expression before it gets fully evaluated. So, its forcing to evaluate that part of the expression before the rest.

With more input, I could provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: What's the difference between !!, !!sym and get()

Comment: Is this concept similar to parentheses in math? `3 / ( 1 + 2 )`?