# Check dataframe with different functions (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to write some functions that take a dataframe and check whether certain variables fulfill certain criteria. For each check I would like to create a new variable "check_" giving the result of the check. Unfortunately, I still struggle to get it right. Can someone help me?

```r
# Some sample data
dat <- data.frame(Q1_1 = c(1, 1, 2, 5, 2, 1),
                  Q1_2 = c(1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 3),
                  Q1_3 = c(4, 3, 3, 5, 1, 3),
                  Q1_4 = c(4, 2, 2, 5, 1, 2),
                  Q1_5 = c(2, 2, 1, 5, 5, 4),
                  Q2_1 = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2),
                  Q2_2 = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1),
                  Q2_3 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1),
                  age = c(22,36,20,27,13, 9))


# Some checker-functions

check_age <- function(.df, agevar = "age"){
  #' Function should check if the age value is within a certain range
  #' and create a new variable "check_age" giving the result of the check

  .df %>% mutate(check_age = ifelse(age > 100, FALSE, TRUE),
                 check_age = ifelse(age < 4, FALSE, TRUE))
  ???
}

check_sameAnswers <- function(.df, varname = "Q1_"){
  #' Function should check whether all sub Of a question (e.g. Q1_1 to Q1_5) have the
  #' same values and create a new variable "check_sameAnswers" giving the result of the check.
  #' It should be TRUE if Q1_1, Q1_2, ... have the value 5 for example, otherwise FALSE
  
  ???
}


# Apply checker functions to dataframe in "dplyr-style"
dat <- dat %>% 
          check_age(agevar = "age") %>%
          check_sameAnswers(varname = "Q1_")
```

Comment: Not related to your code problem, but for these kinds of checks, you should look into the [pointblank](https://rich-iannone.github.io/pointblank/) package. Excellent data validation tools in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bloxx already mentioned, your `ifelse` is the first problem. Those conditions are evaluated sequentially (same would happen if you would use `dplyr::case_when`). Its not a problem with the functions, but the way you declare the conditions, it should be one condition, not two. But you also have a second problem in your first function - you call `age` variable directly from the data frame (by data masking), not the column corresponding to the column name stored in argument `agevar`. This is why I used `deparse(substitute())` to get the column corresponding to the column name in `agevar`.

I changed the first values in the `age` column so you can see the results of the function.

In your second function you want to check if different items have the same values across colums. In the `tidyverse` you generally use `rowwise` for this. `contains` was used to give you more flexibility when specifying column prefixes that define your grouppings.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Some sample data
dat <- data.frame(Q1_1 = c(1, 1, 2, 5, 2, 1),
                  Q1_2 = c(1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 3),
                  Q1_3 = c(4, 3, 3, 5, 1, 3),
                  Q1_4 = c(4, 2, 2, 5, 1, 2),
                  Q1_5 = c(2, 2, 1, 5, 5, 4),
                  Q2_1 = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2),
                  Q2_2 = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1),
                  Q2_3 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1),
                  age = c(1,101,20,27,13, 9))   # here changed first 2 values


# Some checker-functions

check_age <- function(.df, agevar = "age"){
  #' Function should check if the age value is within a certain range
  #' and create a new variable "check_age" giving the result of the check
  
  age <- deparse(substitute(agevar))
  
  .df %>% mutate(check_age = ifelse(age > 100 | age < 4, FALSE, TRUE))
  
}

check_sameAnswers <- function(.df, varname = "Q1_"){
  #' Function should check whether all sub Of a question (e.g. Q1_1 to Q1_5) have the
  #' same values and create a new variable "check_sameAnswers" giving the result of the check.
  #' It should be TRUE if Q1_1, Q1_2, ... have the value 5 for example, otherwise FALSE
  
  .df %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(check_sameAnswers = length(unique(c_across(contains(varname)))) == 1)
}


# Apply checker functions to dataframe in "dplyr-style"
dat %>% 
  check_age(agevar = "age") %>%
  check_sameAnswers(varname = "Q1_") %>%
  dplyr::select(-contains("Q2_"))                   # just for uncluttered printing
#> # A tibble: 6 x 8
#> # Rowwise: 
#>    Q1_1  Q1_2  Q1_3  Q1_4  Q1_5   age check_age check_sameAnswers
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>     <lgl>            
#> 1     1     1     4     4     2     1 FALSE     FALSE            
#> 2     1     2     3     2     2   101 FALSE     FALSE            
#> 3     2     3     3     2     1    20 TRUE      FALSE            
#> 4     5     5     5     5     5    27 TRUE      TRUE             
#> 5     2     1     1     1     5    13 TRUE      FALSE            
#> 6     1     3     3     2     4     9 TRUE      FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

UPDATE: Dynamic naming inside mutate is possible by using `:=` to dynamically assign to dynamically named column `"check_{varname}"`. In our case you can extend the logic of `check_sameAnswer` so that each time you use it for a Q1_, Q2_, ... prefix it returns a column containing that name with the check for those particular columns.

```
check_sameAnsDyn <- function(.df, varname = "Q1_"){

  .df %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate("check_sameAnsDyn_{varname}" := length(unique(c_across(contains(varname)))) == 1)
}


dat %>% 
  check_sameAnsDyn(varname = "Q1_") %>%
  check_sameAnsDyn(varname = "Q2_") %>%
  dplyr::select(-age)                   # just for uncluttered printing

# A tibble: 6 x 10
# Rowwise: 
   Q1_1  Q1_2  Q1_3  Q1_4  Q1_5  Q2_1  Q2_2  Q2_3 check_sameAnsDyn_Q1_ check_sameAnsDyn_Q2_
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>                <lgl>               
1     1     1     4     4     2     1     2     1 FALSE                FALSE               
2     1     2     3     2     2     2     1     1 FALSE                FALSE               
3     2     3     3     2     1     1     1     1 FALSE                TRUE                
4     5     5     5     5     5     2     1     2 TRUE                 FALSE               
5     2     1     1     1     5     1     2     2 FALSE                FALSE               
6     1     3     3     2     4     2     1     1 FALSE                FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks, thats very helpful! Just a short follow-up question: In `check_sameAnswers()` how can I call the newly created variable `check_<varname>` (dynamically, using the "varname" argument) instead of `check_sameAnswers`?

Comment: You are welcome. You can use dynamic variable naming inside `mutate` using `"check_{varname}"` so that string from `varname` is pasted in the name and use `:=` for dynamic assignment. See more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003574/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-dplyr. This being said you should modify the code I provided if you want to do this because `check_sameAnswers` function is predicated on the assumption that `varname` is a common string pattern that defines a group of columns.

Comment: If this answer was a satisfactory solution to your problem, please consider accepting it so that others know one was found.

Comment: `check <- function(.df, varname) {
 .df %>% mutate(check_{varname} = "xy")
}` I'm still having troubles setting a dynamic variable name within a function.

Answer (score 1):

You can embrace the argument to use variables (from data masking) in your function

##### Functions

```
library(dplyr)

check_age <- function(data, age_var, start = 0, end = 0){
  data %>% 
  mutate(between = ifelse({{age_var}} >= start & {{age_var}} <= end,T,F))
}

check_sameAnswers <- function(data, cols){
  data %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(same = length(unique(c_across(starts_with(cols)))) == 1) %>% 
  ungroup()
}
```

Use

```
dat %>% 
  check_age(age, 30, 40) %>% 
  check_sameAnswers(cols="Q1")
# A tibble: 6 × 11
   Q1_1  Q1_2  Q1_3  Q1_4  Q1_5  Q2_1  Q2_2  Q2_3   age between same 
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>   <lgl>
1     1     1     4     4     2     1     2     1    22 FALSE   FALSE
2     1     2     3     2     2     2     1     1    36 TRUE    FALSE
3     2     3     3     2     1     1     1     1    20 FALSE   FALSE
4     5     5     5     5     5     2     1     2    27 FALSE   TRUE 
5     2     1     1     1     5     1     2     2    13 FALSE   FALSE
6     1     3     3     2     4     2     1     1     9 FALSE   FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your ifelse statement. Try this:

```
check_age <- function(.df, agevar = "age"){
  #' Function should check if the age value is within a certain range
  #' and create a new variable "check_age" giving the result of the check
  
  .df %>% mutate(check_age = ifelse(age > 100 | age < 4, FALSE, TRUE))

}

check_sameAnswers <- function(.df, varname = "Q1_"){
  #' Function should check whether all sub Of a question (e.g. Q1_1 to Q1_5) have the
  #' same values and create a new variable "check_sameAnswers" giving the result of the check.
  #' It should be TRUE if Q1_1, Q1_2, ... have the value 5 for example, otherwise FALSE
  .df %>% mutate(sameAnswers = ifelse(length(unique(dat$Q1_2)) == 1, TRUE, FALSE))
}


# Apply checker functions to dataframe in "dplyr-style"
dat <- dat %>% 
  check_age(agevar = "age") %>%
  check_sameAnswers(varname = "Q1_")
dat
```

Comment: What @D. Studer is asking for in the second function is to get TRUE/FALSE when all columns starting with `Q1_` (i.e. Q1_1 ... Q1_5) have the same value. Your solution does not do that, it checks if all values in Q1_2 are the same (i.e. if Q1_2 has zero variance).