# !! not making a string a variable name

Tags: r, string, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm experimenting dynamic variable name. Comparing

```
iris %>% mutate(Species.x=Species)
```

and

```
iris %>% mutate(Species.x=(!!"Species"))
```

They don't match because the latter uses Species as the entire column. Why? (I'm just trying to understand the reasoning and what I really want is to mutate variables dynamically. I saw this post [Use dynamic name for new column/variable in `dplyr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003574/use-dynamic-name-for-new-column-variable-in-dplyr) but it didn't work. Is it because I'm using a newer version of dplyr?)

Comment: Use `.data` `iris %>% mutate(Species.x=(.data[["Species"]]))` or convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`) `iris %>% mutate(Species.x=!!rlang::sym("Species"))`

Comment: What's the purpose of `sym` and why isn't `!!` working immediately?

Comment: I've never seen `!!` used directly on a string. Have you read through the `?"!!"` help page?

Comment: You may check the [vignette](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/topic-metaprogramming.html) regarding this