# Using a reference table of variable names in a function and working row wise

Tags: r

I have a long list of time diff calculations I want to make. Given the names of the columns are long and contain spaces (pulled from an API) I've created a table of the variable names to be used for each operation:

```
stage_refs <- structure(list(new.diff.var = c("time diff 1", "time diff 2", 
                            "time diff 3", "time diff 4"), var.1 = c("time value 2", "time value 3", 
                                                                     "time value 4", "time value 5"), var.2 = c("time value 1", "time value 2", 
                                                                                                                "time value 3", "time value 4")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), spec = structure(list(
                                                                                                                  cols = list(new.diff.var = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                         "collector")), var.1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "collector")), var.2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And a date frame of dates with missing values for where no dates are as yet recorded:

```
date_values <- structure(list(`time value 1` = structure(c(18993, 18993, 18993, 
NA), class = "Date"), `time value 2` = structure(c(19024, NA, 
19026, 19027), class = "Date"), `time value 3` = structure(c(NA, 
19084, 19085, 19086), class = "Date"), `time value 4` = structure(c(19113, 
19114, NA, 19116), class = "Date"), `time value 5` = structure(c(19174, 
19175, 19176, 19177), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -4L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

In the production data set there are up to 20 diff time calculations to make, hence why I've put in a table so I can use a function such as:

```
library(tidyverse)

difftime_fun <- function(x, y, z) {
  date_values |>
    mutate(!!x = difftime(y, z))
}
```

... to create a new column from x by the calculation between y & z and then apply this function row-wise over `stage_refs` using a loop:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(time_diff_stages)) {
  difftime_fun(
    stage_refs$new.diff.var[[i]],
    stage_refs$var.1[[i]],
    stage_refs$var.2[[i]]
 )
```

What I want is as many timediff columns added to `date_values` as rows in `stage_refs` using the variable names from `stage_refs` for assignment of the cols and for the calculations.

There are 2 places I'm stuck:

1. I'm running into non-standard-evaluation problems with using the variable names in the function. I've tried combinations of `!!`, `{{ }}`, `eval` etc and can't make sense of it.
2. I suspect there's a better way than using the loop to go row-wise using `apply` or some such, but not solving (1) means it's hard to trial and error using `apply`.

I have looked at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003574/use-dynamic-name-for-new-column-variable-in-dplyr), but can't make sense as to how to use for this problem.

Thanks.

For clarification the final df would have the following columns:

```
[1] "time value 1" "time value 2" "time value 3" "time value 4" "time value 5" "time diff 1" 
[7] "time diff 2"  "time diff 3"  "time diff 4"
```

Comment: For clarification, can you show what your expected output would looks like?

Comment: @Aron I've added the column names to the OP above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve your desired result you could first rewrite your function by adding a data argument and using the `.data` pronoun which allows to access dat columns passed as character string. After doing so you could e.g. use `purrr::reduce` or base `Reduce` to loop over the rows of your
`stage_refs` dataframe and apply your `difftime_fun` to create your diff time columns.

Note: In row 4 of your `stage_refs` a column `"time value 7"` was specified which was not part of your example data. I simply replaced it by `"time value 4"`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

difftime_fun <- function(.data, x, y, z) {
  .data |>
    mutate("{x}" := difftime(.data[[y]], .data[[z]]))
}

purrr::reduce(seq(nrow(stage_refs)), function(.x, i) {
  difftime_fun(.x,
    stage_refs$new.diff.var[[i]],
    stage_refs$var.1[[i]],
    stage_refs$var.2[[i]]
  )
}, .init = date_values)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 9
#>   time val…¹ time val…² time val…³ time val…⁴ time val…⁵ time …⁶ time …⁷ time …⁸
#>   <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <drtn>  <drtn>  <drtn> 
#> 1 2022-01-01 2022-02-01 NA         2022-05-01 2022-07-01 31 days NA days NA days
#> 2 2022-01-01 NA         2022-04-02 2022-05-02 2022-07-02 NA days NA days 30 days
#> 3 2022-01-01 2022-02-03 2022-04-03 NA         2022-07-03 33 days 59 days NA days
#> 4 NA         2022-02-04 2022-04-04 2022-05-04 2022-07-04 NA days 59 days 30 days
#> # … with 1 more variable: `time diff 4` <drtn>, and abbreviated variable names
#> #   ¹​`time value 1`, ²​`time value 2`, ³​`time value 3`, ⁴​`time value 4`,
#> #   ⁵​`time value 5`, ⁶​`time diff 1`, ⁷​`time diff 2`, ⁸​`time diff 3`
```

Comment: thanks - I've corrected the error. Will test.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to build function calls from your reference data frame using `pmap()` and to splice those inside of `mutate()`.  This will be more efficient than iteratively calling `mutate()`.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

date_values %>%
  mutate(!!!setNames(pmap(stage_refs, ~ call("difftime", sym(..2), sym(..3))), stage_refs$new.diff.var))

# A tibble: 4 × 9
  `time value 1` `time value 2` `time value 3` `time value 4` `time value 5` `time diff 1` `time diff 2` `time diff 3` `time diff 4`
  <date>         <date>         <date>         <date>         <date>         <drtn>        <drtn>        <drtn>        <drtn>       
1 2022-01-01     2022-02-01     NA             2022-05-01     2022-07-01     31 days       NA days       NA days       61 days      
2 2022-01-01     NA             2022-04-02     2022-05-02     2022-07-02     NA days       NA days       30 days       61 days      
3 2022-01-01     2022-02-03     2022-04-03     NA             2022-07-03     33 days       59 days       NA days       NA days      
4 NA             2022-02-04     2022-04-04     2022-05-04     2022-07-04     NA days       59 days       30 days       61 days
```