# Adding a flag column for variables

Tags: r

I am trying to add a column of flagged data, where "Secret Identity is 0, and everything else is 1. My table currently looks like this;

name ID

Spider-Man        Secret Identity

Captain America   Public Identity

Wolverine         Public Identity

Iron Man          Public Identity

Thor              No Dual Identity

Benjamin Grimm    Public Identity

Reed Richards     Public Identity

Otto Octavius     Secret Identity

Hulk              Public Identity

Scott Summers     Public Identity

Johnathan Storm   Public Identity

Katherine Pryde   Secret Identity

As for coding it;

`characters %>% mutate(FLAG = case_when(ID == "Secret Identity" ~ 0, TRUE ~ 1))`

This seems to work, however I also needed a new field or column listing either '0' or '1' depending on the ID field. Like this;

name              ID                Flag

Spider-Man        Secret Identity   1

Captain America   Public Identity   0

Wolverine         Public Identity   0

Iron Man          Public Identity   0

Thor              No Dual Identity  0

Benjamin Grimm    Public Identity   0

Reed Richards     Public Identity   0

Otto Octavius     Secret Identity   1

Hulk              Public Identity   0

Scott Summers     Public Identity   0

Johnathan Storm   Public Identity   0

Katherine Pryde   Secret Identity   1

Comment: In general, it's a better idea to use `logical` class instead of integers 1 and 0 to represent "yes"/"no" binary data. https://sscc.wisc.edu/sscc/pubs/dwr/logical.html

Comment: As for your problem, don't forget that you can use regular programming constructs like `for` loops to construct several columns automatically. This is a case where Dplyr gets a [little clunky](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26003574/2954547), and base R works a bit nicer, because in base R you can just operate on the column names as regular text data.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.