# Is there a way to write dplyr functions with a constant column name?

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I'm trying to write a function that will compute new variables in mutate() or summarize() from dplyr, where at least one column in the function is constant (not variable, so not passed as an argument to the function). However, when I try to do this, R doesn't recognize that the column exists ("object 'l' not found"). How can I use constant column names in a function used within mutate/summarize?

Reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
    x = rep(c("A", "B"), times = 10),
    y = rnorm(20),
    l = rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), each = 10)
)

foo <- function(y) {
    total <- n() # total count
    n <- sum(l) # count of TRUE
    pct <- round(100 * n / total, 1) # percent of TRUE
    pct
}

df %>%
    group_by(x) %>%
    summarize(
      n = n(),
      result = foo(y = y)
)
```

Note that I do NOT want the function itself to use summarize(), since I'm computing other columns within the summarize function.

I've tried replacing l with {{l}} and !!sym(l). I've also tried setting l = l as a default argument in the function. None of this seems to work.

Comment: I suppose you could use `df$l`, but I'm guessing that's not what you had in mind

Comment: one alternative is `map_dbl(y, \(y) round(100 * sum(l) / n(), 1))`

Comment: I think it has to do with the environment the function is called within. The anonymous function above works like that, but then making it it's own function, it stops working

Comment: some reading https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#data--and-env-variables

Comment: Another alternative is to add `l` to your function and then call it like: `foo(y, l)`.

Comment: Relevant question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003574/use-dynamic-name-for-new-column-variable-in-dplyr?rq=1

Comment: Looks like the question above is dealing with a different problem - how to assign column names within mutate, vs. how to identify a constant column within any dataframe that's passed to the function.

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you didn't want to pass it as an argument to the function, but is there a reason for that? If that variable is always gonna have a default value, why not passing it to the function? I think the code below does what you expected:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  x = rep(c("A", "B"), times = 10),
  y = rnorm(20),
  l = rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), each = 10)
)

foo <- function(y, l) {
  total <- n() # total count
  n <- sum({{l}}) # count of TRUE
  pct <- round(100 * n / total, 1) # percent of TRUE
  pct
}

df %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  summarize(
    n = n(),
    result = foo(y = y, l = l)
  )
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I ended up settling on. I think ideally I wouldn't need to set l just to reduce repetition, since it will always have the same value for my use case, but if I can't achieve that then this works.